# If registers are so blazingly fast, why don't we have more of them?

Tags: performance, history, cpu-registers, assembly

In 32bit, we had 8 "general purpose" registers. With 64bit, the amount doubles, but it seems independent of the 64bit change itself.
Now, if registers are so fast (no memory access), why aren't there more of them naturally? Shouldn't CPU builders work as many registers as possible into the CPU? What is the logical restriction to why we only have the amount we have?

Comment: CPUs and GPUs hide latency primarily by caches and massive-multithreading respectively. So, CPUs have (or need) few registers, whereas GPUs have tens of thousands of registers. See my [survey paper on GPU register file](https://www.academia.edu/23514653/A_Survey_of_Techniques_for_Architecting_and_Managing_GPU_Register_File) which discusses all these trade-offs and factors.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

There's many reasons you don't just have a huge number of registers:

- They're highly linked to most pipeline stages. For starters, you need to track their lifetime, and forward results back to previous stages. The complexity gets intractable very quickly, and the number of wires (literally) involved grows at the same rate. It's expensive on area, which ultimately means it's expensive on power, price and performance after a certain point.
- It takes up instruction encoding space. 16 registers takes up 4 bits for source and destination, and another 4 if you have 3-operand instructions (e.g ARM). That's an awful lot of instruction set encoding space taken up just to specify the register. This eventually impacts decoding, code size and again complexity.
- There's better ways to achieve the same result...

These days we really do have lots of registers - they're just not explicitly programmed. We have "register renaming". While you only access a small set (8-32 registers), they're actually backed by a much larger set (e.g 64-256). The CPU then tracks the visibility of each register, and allocates them to the renamed set. For example, you can load, modify, then store to a register many times in a row, and have each of these operations actually performed independently depending on cache misses etc. In ARM:

```
ldr r0, [r4]
add r0, r0, #1
str r0, [r4]
ldr r0, [r5]
add r0, r0, #1
str r0, [r5]
```

Cortex A9 cores do register renaming, so the first load to "r0" actually goes to a renamed virtual register - let's call it "v0". The load, increment and store happen on "v0". Meanwhile, we also perform a load/modify/store to r0 again, but that'll get renamed to "v1" because this is an entirely independent sequence using r0. Let's say the load from the pointer in "r4" stalled due to a cache miss. That's ok - we don't need to wait for "r0" to be ready. Because it's renamed, we can run the next sequence with "v1" (also mapped to r0) - and perhaps that's a cache hit and we just had a huge performance win.

```
ldr v0, [v2]
add v0, v0, #1
str v0, [v2]
ldr v1, [v3]
add v1, v1, #1
str v1, [v3]
```

I think x86 is up to a gigantic number of renamed registers these days (ballpark 256). That would mean having 8 bits times 2 for every instruction just to say what the source and destination is. It would massively increase the number of wires needed across the core, and its size. So there's a sweet spot around 16-32 registers which most designers have settled for, and for out-of-order CPU designs, register renaming is the way to mitigate it.

**Edit**: The importance of out-of-order execution and register renaming on this. Once you have OOO, the number of registers doesn't matter so much, because they're just "temporary tags" and get renamed to the much larger virtual register set. You don't want the number to be too small, because it gets difficult to write small code sequences. This is a problem for x86-32, because the limited 8 registers means a lot of temporaries end up going through the stack, and the core needs extra logic to forward reads/writes to memory. If you don't have OOO, you're usually talking about a small core, in which case a large register set is a poor cost/performance benefit.

So there's a natural sweet spot for register bank size which maxes out at about 32 architected registers for most classes of CPU. x86-32 has 8 registers and it's definitely too small. ARM went with 16 registers and it's a good compromise. 32 registers is slightly too many if anything - you end up not needing the last 10 or so.

None of this touches on the extra registers you get for SSE and other vector floating point coprocessors. Those make sense as an extra set because they run independently of the integer core, and don't grow the CPU's complexity exponentially.

Comment: Excellent answer - I'd like to throw another reason into the mix - the more registers one has, the more time it takes to throw them onto / pull them off of the stack when context switching.  Definitely not the major issue, but a consideration.

Comment: @WillA good point. However, architectures with lots of registers have ways of mitigating this cost. The ABI will usually have callee-save of most registers, so you only have to save a core set. Context switching is usually expensive enough that the extra save/restore doesn't cost a lot compared to all the other red tape. SPARC actually works around this by making the register bank a "window" on a memory area, so it scales with this somewhat (kind of hand-waved that).

Comment: Consider my mind blown by such a thorough answer which I for sure didn't expect. Also, thanks for that explanation on why we don't really need that many named registers, that's very interesting! I really enjoyed reading your answer, because I'm totally interested in what goes on "under the hood". :) I'm gonna wait a bit more before accepting an answer, because you never know, but my +1 is sure.

Comment: regardless of where the responsibility for saving registers lies the time it takes is administrative overhead. OK so context switching may not be the most-often occurring case, but interrupts are. Hand-coded routines may economize on registers but if drivers are written in C chances are that the interrupt-declared function will save every single register, call the isr and then restore all the saved registers. IA-32 had an interrupt advantage with its 15-20 regs compared to 32+something regs of RISC architectures.

Comment: Excellent answer, but I'll disagree with direct comparison of "renamed" registers with "real" adressable ones. On x86-32, even with 256 internal registers you can't use more than 8 temporary values stored in registers in any single point of execution. Basically, register renaming is only a curious byproduct of OOE, nothing more.

Comment: Exactly what noop said: too few architectural registers leads to more wasted instructions spilling/reloading from memory.  Someone published a paper where they examined the effect on instruction count, and the overhead-reduction benefit from 8->16 was much higher than the benefit from 16->32.  (See [the paper](http://researchbank.rmit.edu.au/eserv/rmit:2517/n2001000381.pdf), and [my comments on electronics.SE on a duplicate of this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256854/why-dont-we-have-more-registers-in-microprocessors)

Answer (score 13):

#### We *Do* Have More of Them

Because almost every instruction must select 1, 2, or 3 architecturally visible registers, expanding the number of them would increase code size by several bits on each instruction and so reduce code density. It also increases the amount of *[context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_%28computing%29)* that must be saved as thread state, and partially saved in a function's *[activation record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_record).*  These operations occur frequently. Pipeline interlocks must check a scoreboard for every register and this has quadratic time and space complexity. And perhaps the biggest reason is simply compatibility with the already-defined instruction set.

But it turns out, thanks to *[register renaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming),* we really do have lots of registers available, and we don't even need to save them. The CPU actually has many register sets, and it automatically switches between them as your code exeutes. It does this purely to get you more registers.

*Example:*

```
load  r1, a  # x = a
store r1, x
load  r1, b  # y = b
store r1, y
```

In an architecture that has only r0-r7, the following code may be rewritten automatically by the CPU as something like:

```
load  r1, a
store r1, x
load  r10, b
store r10, y
```

In this case r10 is a hidden register that is substituted for r1 temporarily.  The CPU can tell that the the value of r1 is never used again after the first store. This allows the first load to be delayed (even an on-chip cache hit usually takes several cycles) without requiring the delay of the second load or the second store.

Comment: A function prologue only needs to save as many [call-preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078/224132) registers as it actually uses. (Although an unwise compiler might save/restore too many, instead of accepting a spill and reload elsewhere in the function, if there were too many to choose from.  Especially in a function with an early-out condition before it gets to the code that might use that many regs, if the compiler doesn't shrink-wrap opt)  And call-clobbered registers don't need to get saved at all; they can be used freely as scratch space between calls and inside leaf functions.

Comment: Register renaming allows efficient register reuse without false dependencies, but it's not perfect.  It doesn't help when you actually want more than 16 different values "live" at once in regs, e.g. to unroll with 8 or 10 different dependency chains to let the CPU find instruction-level parallelism.  (That's why AVX-512 doubled the number of FP/vector regs to 32, since FP code is more likely to want a lot of constants, and/or to [unroll with multiple accumulators to hide FP latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell).)

Answer (score 3):

They add registers all of the time, but they are often tied to special purpose instructions (e.g. SIMD, SSE2, etc) or require compiling to a specific CPU architecture, which lowers portability.  Existing instructions often work on specific registers and couldn't take advantage of other registers if they were available.  Legacy instruction set and all.

Answer (score 1):

To add a little interesting info here you'll notice that having 8 same sized registers allows opcodes to maintain consistency with hexadecimal notation.  For example the instruction `push ax` is opcode 0x50 on x86 and goes up to 0x57 for the last register di.  Then the instruction `pop ax` starts at 0x58 and goes up to 0x5F `pop di` to complete the first base-16.  Hexadecimal consistency is maintained with 8 registers per a size.

Comment: On x86/64 the REX instruction prefixes extend the register indices with more bits.