# starting point of ELF executable file?

Tags: linux, disassembly, entry-point

I compile following C program on lubuntu 12.10 with anjuta

```
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

the file name is foobar

then I open up terminal and write command

```
ndisasm foobar -b 32 1>asm.txt
```

(disassemble foobar with 32 bit instruction option and save disassembled result to asm.txt)

I open up asm.txt
there are many 0x0000 and miss-understandable code.

the instruction `jg 0x47(0x7F45) on 0x00000000 and dec esp(0x4C) on 0x00000002`
 seems ELF file format signature. 
(because the hex code 0x454c46 is 'ELF' in ascii)

the Linux might load this code to memory and don't jump to 0x00000000 because there is no executable code.

I have questions here.

1. how do I know the address of starting address?
2. which code is OK to ignore?(maybe many 0x0000 would be OK to ignore but what else?)

Comment: Why not `objdump -d foobar`? It will disassemble only executable (text) sections of elf file. Also try `readelf -e foobar` to get info about sections and to find entry address.

Comment: is it possible to get starting point by hands?

Comment: Check Elf Header: http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/1998-04-29/ch4.eheader.html - e_entry field. But you need also parse Program header http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/1998-04-29/ch5.pheader.html and find all PT_LOAD segments to translate virtual address to file offset. Here is quick intro into ELF and loading process: http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even for the simplest program like yours, `gcc` is linking some libraries and some object files (notably `crt0.o` which calls your `main` and contains `_start`, the ELF starting point). And your binary is probably dynamically linked to some `libc.so.6` so needs the dynamic linker (use `ldd foobar` to find out).  Use `gcc -v` to understand what `gcc` is doing. And [objdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_objdump.htm) has a lot of interesting flags or options.

You may also want to read the [Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/), the [X86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224188/x86-64-assembly-conventions-saving-argument-registers), [the X86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), [these notes on X86-64 programming](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~apt/cs322/x86-64.pdf), etc