# Comparing first argument in argv to a char

Tags: assembly, x86-64

According to the standard calling convention the arguments in argv are stored in the register rsi.

Assuming, my argc is 2 and my command line is something like:

```
./program a
```

I want to compare if something is equal to "a".
I have the following code:

```
mov r12, rsi
mov r13, 0
mov r14, qword[r12+r13*8]
cmp r14, "a"
je Success

; Code here that displays error

Success:
; etc.
```

So, I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but it doesn't jump to success, but it should right?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @David, r14 is loaded with argv[0], so it’s not going to crash. But it should set r13 to 1 to load argv[1].

Comment: Vroryn, you need to compare each byte that r14 points to with each byte of the string you are comparing to.

Comment: @prl Setting r13 to 1 solved this. Thank you!

Comment: @prl I would be grateful if you could explain, why the argument is loaded in arv[1], shouldn't the first argument be loaded in arg[0]?

Comment: C11 standard: "If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name".

Comment: FWIW, there is no "standard" calling convention. I assume you mean the System V 64 bit ABI, which is used by a number of OSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're overcomplicating this with more instructions than necessary
- `a` will be `argv[1]`, but you're loading `argv[0]` (by convention the program name, but could be a NULL pointer or arbitrary string if your program is invoked with `execve()` from something other than a normal shell).
- you're comparing `"a"` with the pointer value, not with the pointed-to string data.

i.e. the C version of what you wrote is

```
if( (intptr_t)argv[0] == "a" ){
    success:
}
```

---

For an assemble-time-constant index, you should just use a displacement instead of an index register.  You can write it in a way that looks nice for humans using an assemble-time expression like `1 * 8` or `0 * 8`.

```
global main
main:
    cmp   edi, 2
    jb    too_few_args        ; if(argc<2) avoid segfaults in both of the next 2 insns

    mov   rdx, [rsi + 8*1]    ; r14 = argv[1]
    cmp   byte [rdx], "a"     ; argv[1][0] == 'a'
    je    success

      ...

success:
     xor  eax,eax
     ret                   ; return 0
```

`r14` is a call-preserved register in the x86-64 System V ABI, so if your `main` returns instead of `call exit`, you should leave R14 with the same value it had on entry.    [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call)

RDX is call-clobbered, so it's a good choice for a scratch register.

It also saves a byte of code-size to use RDX or some other scratch register that doesn't need a REX prefix instead of R8..15.  The qword `mov` will always need a REX prefix, but the byte `cmp` won't.