# Keeping track of caller and callee functions with only 16 registers in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, calling-convention

I am confused about those *caller-saved* and *callee-saved* registers. What if a function is both caller and callee?

Say the `main` function calls function `P`, and function `P` calls function `Q`. In this case, `P` being both callee (for `main`) and caller (for `Q`), then which register will the assembly use?

Comment: usually you save them with push/pop around the function.  Look at compiler output for examples.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of simplicity, I will assume the **System V ABI**, and limit this explanation for **integer and pointer parameters**. For a much more detailed description of the calling conventions for Unix refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/8012646).

---

The first six arguments are passed to the function in the registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8` and `r9`. These registers are *caller-saved*, i.e., they may not be preserved between function calls, since they *callee* may clobber them (a more suitable term for them would be *call-clobbered* registers).

Let's declare `Q` as:

```
int Q(int, int, int, int, int, int);
```

That is, `Q` takes six integers so that the compiler-generated code is forced to use all those six caller-saved registers.

Now, let's define `P` in this way:

```
int P(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {  
    return Q(a, b, c, d, e, f) + Q(f, e, d, c, b, a);
}
```

This way the compiler will run out of caller-saved registers, and it will be forced to use *callee-saved* registers for the code of the function above.

The code above generates the following assembly:

```
P:
  // save rbx, rbp, r12, r13, r14 and r15 onto the stack
  // copy rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 and r9 into those registers
  pushq %r15
  movl %esi, %r15d
  pushq %r14
  movl %edx, %r14d
  pushq %r13
  movl %ecx, %r13d
  pushq %r12
  movl %r8d, %r12d
  pushq %rbp
  movl %r9d, %ebp
  pushq %rbx
  movl %edi, %ebx
  subq $24, %rsp
  call Q // <-- 1st call to Q (may clobber rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 and r9)

  // prepare rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 and r9 for the 2nd call to Q
  movl %ebx, %r9d
  movl %r15d, %r8d
  movl %r14d, %ecx
  movl %r13d, %edx
  movl %r12d, %esi
  movl %ebp, %edi
  movl %eax, 12(%rsp)
  call Q // <-- 2nd call to Q
  addl 12(%rsp), %eax
  addq $24, %rsp
  popq %rbx
  popq %rbp
  popq %r12
  popq %r13
  popq %r14
  popq %r15
  ret
```

The call to `Q` is allowed to clobber the registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8` and `r9` (among others). These registers contain the arguments of the call to `P` (i.e., `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`, respectively) and their values are still needed for the second call to `Q`. For this reason, the registers `rbx`, `rbp`, `r12`, `r13`, `r14` and `r15` are used to copy those registers before the call to `Q` in order preserve the original arguments `P` was called with.

`Q` is not allowed to clobber these registers that are used to save the callee-saved registers, since these are *caller-saved* registers, i.e., their value has to be preserved between function calls (another term for them would be *call-preserved* registers). Therefore, the code in the function `P` saves these registers onto the stack with `push` before clobbering them and restores them with `pop` from the stack before the control flow has returned from `P` (`P` is the *caller* of `Q` here). The net effect that the caller of `P` will see, is that those registers have their original value, the same value they had just before the call to `P`.

Note that the second call to `Q` may clobber the registers `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8` and `r9` as well, but there is no interest in preserving their values, since they are no longer after `Q` returns.

---

For a deeper insight into register clobbering, have a look at [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call).

Comment: There are some call-clobbered regs that aren't used for arg-passing: RAX, R10, and R11.   [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672)  And BTW, I like the terminology "call preserved" vs. "call clobbered", so both terms are looking at things from the same perspective, and don't imply that anything has to be saved.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the tip on terminology! Regarding your 1st sentence, I think that the wording is correct, since I didn't place the definite article before "caller-saved": "*These registers are caller-saved*" instead of "*These registers are **the** caller-saved registers*". Am I missing something here?

Comment: I was looking at the sentence "*The call to Q is allowed to clobber the registers rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 and r9*".  Which is true even without a complete list, but the question was asking about call-clobbered registers in general (e.g. for scratch regs), not just arg-passing.  Probably a good idea to just link that Q&A with the x86-64 SysV register table from somewhere in your answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks again for clarifying!