# Linux perf_events annotation frame pointer confusion

Tags: linux, x86-64, disassembly, perf

I ran `sudo perf record -F 99 find /` followed by `sudo perf report` and selected "Annotate fdopendir" and here are the first seven instructions:

`push   %rbp
push   %rbx
mov    %edi,%esi
mov    %edi,%ebx
mov    $0x1,%edi
sub    $0xa8,%rsp
mov    %rsp,%rbp`

The first instruction appears to be saving the caller's base frame pointer. I believe instructions 2 through 5 are irrelevant to this question but here for completeness. Instructions 6 and 7 are confusing to me. Shouldn't the assignment of rbp to rsp occur *before* subtracting 0xa8 from rsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x86-64 System V ABI doesn't require making a traditional / legacy stack-frame.  This looks *close* to a traditional stack frame setup, but it's definitely not because there's no `mov %rsp, %rbp` right after the first `push %rbp`.

**We're seeing compiler-generated code that simply uses RBP as a temporary register, and is using it to hold a pointer to a local on the stack.**  It's just a coincidence that this happens to involve the instruction `mov %rsp, %rbp` sometime after `push %rbp`.  **This is not making a stack frame.**

In x86-64 System V, RBX and RBP are the only 2 "low 8" registers that are call-preserved, and thus usable without REX prefixes in some cases (e.g. for the push/pop, and when used in addressing modes), saving code-size.  GCC prefers to use them before saving/restoring any of R12..R15.  [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call)  (For pointers, copying them with `mov` always requires a REX prefix for 64-bit operand-size, so there are fewer savings than for 32-bit integers, but gcc still goes for RBX then RBP, in that order, when it needs to save/restore call-preserved regs in a function.)

Disassembly of `/lib/libc.so.6` (glibc) on my system (Arch Linux) shows similar but different code-gen for `fdopendir`.  You stopped the disassembly too soon, before it makes a function call.  That sheds some light on why it wanted a call-preserved temporary register: it wanted the var in a reg across the call.

```
00000000000c1260 <fdopendir>:
   c1260:       55                      push   %rbp
   c1261:       89 fe                   mov    %edi,%esi
   c1263:       53                      push   %rbx
   c1264:       89 fb                   mov    %edi,%ebx
   c1266:       bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
   c126b:       48 81 ec a8 00 00 00    sub    $0xa8,%rsp
   c1272:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00      mov    %fs:0x28,%rax    # stack-check cookie
   c127b:       48 89 84 24 98 00 00 00         mov    %rax,0x98(%rsp)
   c1283:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   c1285:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp      # save a pointer
   c1288:       48 89 ea                mov    %rbp,%rdx      # and pass it as a function arg
   c128b:       e8 90 7d 02 00          callq  e9020 <__fxstat>
   c1290:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
   c1292:       78 6a                   js     c12fe <fdopendir+0x9e>
   c1294:       8b 44 24 18             mov    0x18(%rsp),%eax
   c1298:       25 00 f0 00 00          and    $0xf000,%eax
   c129d:       3d 00 40 00 00          cmp    $0x4000,%eax
   c12a2:       75 4c                   jne    c12f0 <fdopendir+0x90>
   ....

   c12c1:       48 89 e9                mov    %rbp,%rcx      # pass the pointer as the 4th arg
   c12c4:       89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
   c12c6:       31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
   c12c8:       89 df                   mov    %ebx,%edi
   c12ca:       e8 d1 f7 ff ff          callq  c0aa0 <__alloc_dir>
   c12cf:       48 8b 8c 24 98 00 00 00         mov    0x98(%rsp),%rcx
   c12d7:       64 48 33 0c 25 28 00 00 00      xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx     # check the stack cookie
   c12e0:       75 38                   jne    c131a <fdopendir+0xba>
   c12e2:       48 81 c4 a8 00 00 00    add    $0xa8,%rsp
   c12e9:       5b                      pop    %rbx
   c12ea:       5d                      pop    %rbp
   c12eb:       c3                      retq
```

This is pretty silly code-gen; gcc could have simply used `mov %rsp, %rcx` the 2nd time it needed it.  I'd call this a missed-optimization.  It never needed that pointer in a call-preserved register because it always knew where it was relative to RSP.

(Even if it hadn't been exactly at RSP+0, `lea something(%rsp), %rdx` and `lea something(%rsp), %rcx` would have been totally fine the two times it was needed, with probably less total cost than saving/restoring RBP + the required `mov` instructions.)

Or it could have used `mov 0x18(%rbp),%eax` instead of rsp to save a byte of code-size in that addressing mode.  Avoiding direct references to RSP between function calls reduces the amount of stack-sync uops Intel CPUs need to insert.

Comment: Yes, I did stop the disassembly too soon. The next five instructions indeed are setting up a function call:
`mov    %rbp,%rdx
mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
mov    %rax,0x98(%rsp)
xor    %eax,%eax
callq  10f7b0 <__fxstat@@GLIBC_2.2.5>`