# Are rdi and rsi caller saved or callee saved registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

From the wikipedia x86 calling convention, it says that for the Microsoft x64 calling convention:

> The registers RBX, RBP, **RDI, RSI**, RSP, R12, R13, R14, and R15 are considered nonvolatile (callee-saved).

But for System V AMD64 ABI:

> If the callee wishes to use registers RBX, RBP, and R12–R15, it must restore their original values before returning control to the caller.

It did not mention anything about rdi and rsi.

I also read that *%rax, %rcx, %rdx, **%rdi, %rsi**, %rsp, and %r8-r11 are considered caller-save registers* (from a pdf)

My question is, is calling convention various across different platform?(I try to write some libc function in asm for unix environment)

I could not find any article discussing about this topic, resources to this topic will be helpful as well. I wanted to know the advantage and disadvantage of these conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, in all function-calling conventions I'm aware of, the arg-passing registers are call-clobbered.**  (Except for system-call calling conventions, where normally all regs are preserved except a return value, including arg-passing.  Except that x86-64 `syscall` destroys RCX and R11...)

Specifically in x86-64 System V, all registers other than RBX, RBP, RSP, and R12-R15 are call-clobbered.  (That includes xmm0-15, x87/mmx registers, and AVX512 zmm0-31 and k0-k7 mask regs.)

**[What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call) shows the table from the ABI doc**.

---

The calling convention / ABI defines the status of registers as call-preserved or call-clobbered.  Different conventions can make different choices.

And yes, Microsoft Windows chose a different calling convention from everyone else: [Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86)  In Windows x64, RDI is call-preserved, like in most 32-bit calling conventions.

But in x86-64 System V, the designers chose registers from scratch, and (as my answer on that linked question shows) found that using RDI and RSI for the first 2 args saved instructions (when building SPECint with an early x86-64 port of gcc).  Probably because gcc at the time liked to inline `memset` or `memcpy` using `rep stosd`, or the library implementation used that.

(It makes no sense to say that RDI is *intrinsically* call-clobbered, the x86-64 ISA doesn't define that.  It's up to each platform to choose that.)

---

**Terminology:**

I hate the "caller saved" vs. "callee saved" terminology: It's confusing to think from 2 different perspectives (caller and callee), and wrongly implies that every register *does* get saved somewhere on every `call`.  Also, the names only differ by 1 letter, so aren't very visually distinct when reading.

"preserved" or "clobbered" are great; they work from either perspective.  (What a callee will do to your regs, or what you're allowed to do to the caller's regs.)  Moreover, they're self-explanatory.

Comment: so if I overwrite the rdi in a unix environment, and not restoring it, is ok?

Comment: oh I just read ur updated answer, the  preserved and clobbered terminologies sound great, thank you.

Comment: @Sayakura: yes, updated again with a link to the table from the SysV ABI pdf which explicitly documents RDI and RSI as call-clobbered.  I was in a hurry before and didn't see the part of your question where you had only found they were used for arg-passing but hadn't confirmed that that implied they were call-clobbered.  Those aren't inherently the same thing, but in all calling conventions I've ever seen, they are.

Comment: Yes. The operating systems are different here. RSI and RDI are clobbered in Unix x64 but not in Windows. For a complete overview see https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf