# How to Access First Parameter of scanf Call in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, scanf, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

Say I have the following code written in (AT&T) Assembly:

```
push qword 0
push qword 0
mov rax, 2                ;Tell rax we receive 2 floats
mov rdi, floatformat      ;floatformat db "%lf %lf",0

mov rsi, rsp              ;I am assuming my logic flaw is in these two lines
mov rdx, rsp

call scanf
pop rax                   ;Clean up the stack
pop rax

movsd xmm0, [rsi]         ;This does not give the value I want
```

As stated in the comments above, I want `xmm0` to hold the first float the user types in when `call scanf` is performed, but only receive the second float. I am aware that this is most likely due to the `mov rdx, rsp` operation, but if that is not performed, my program does not operate correctly to read in the user inputs.

How can I get the first float the user types in? I have tried researching `scanf` calling conventions but have yet to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%lf` is a `double`, not a single precision `float`.  And no, the 2 args you're passing to scanf are `double *`, *not* `double`, so you should set `AL=0` not `2`.

Anyway, your problem is that you passed the same pointer for both output operands. **And that `scanf` destroys its arg-passing registers, like the calling convention allows it to.**  ([What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call))

The C equivalent is like `scanf("%lf %lf", &b, &b)` after reserving stack space for `double a,b;`

```
    ; assuming stack is 16-byte aligned to start with,
    ; e.g. if your function started with an odd number of pushes

    sub   rsp, 16
    mov   rsi, rsp        ; pointer to low slot
    lea   rdx, [rsp+8]    ; pointer to high slot
    lea   rdi, [rel format_string]    ; use RIP-relative LEA for 64-bit static addresses
    xor   eax,eax         ; 0 FP args in regs to a variadic function
    call  scanf           ; scanf(fmt, &tmp0, &tmp1)

    movaps xmm0, [rsp]     ; load both doubles
    add    rsp, 16         ; now tmp0 and tmp1 are below RSP, in the red-zone

    movsd   xmm1, [rsp-8]  ; or shuffle xmm0 to get tmp1 from the high half.
```

dummy push/pop is usually only worth it (instead of `add rsp, imm8`) for *one* stack slot, and then mostly if you're going to `call` right away instead of explicitly reference RSP.  Doing that will insert a stack-sync uop.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. One question, however: is there any way to do the same action WITHOUT the `lea` operation? I only ask because the textbook I am learning from has yet to mention it, yet has given what I am working on as a practice problem.

Comment: @lawgik: Yes of course, you can emulate it using `mov` and `add`.  It's not magic, just a shift-and-add instruction that can add and put the result in a different register.  Or something like `push rax` / `mov rdx, rsp` / `push rax` / `mov rsi, rsp`.  Other possible sequences to end up with RDI and RDX pointing at 2 different qwords above RSP should be straightforward to come up with, with or without LEA.

Comment: @lawgik: oh BTW, you can't emulate a RIP-relative LEA for position-independent code, except with 32-bit-style `call`/`mov rdi,[rsp]` to read the current program-counter and add some offset.  But you can use inefficient 64-bit absolute addressing like you were doing with `mov rdi, format_string` on most OSes.  [How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](//stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)