# I'm a new to the assembly language. How do I break the recursion loop?

Tags: assembly, x86, primes, att

I'm new to the assembly language. I'm creating a prime factorization function in AT&T x64/GNU syntax.

Here is..

---

```
.data
.text
.global main
.prime_end: .string "End\n"
.fact_end: .string "Finish\n"
.fact_print: .string "%d\n"

prime: 
mov %rsi, %rax
    mov $0, %rdi
    cmp $2, %rax
    jl prime_end

    jmp prime_base

prime_base:    # r10 = 1
    mov $1, %r10
    jmp prime_start

prime_start:    # r10 + 1 = 2
    inc %r10
    jmp prime_check

prime_check:
    cqto
    div %r10    # rsi = 10, rax = 10, rax / r10 = 10/2 

    cmp $0, %rdx    # rdx = 0, rax = 5
    jne prime_start

    jmp fact_check

fact_check:    # rsi = 10, rax = 10
    mov %rsi, %rax
    cqto
    div %r10    # 10 / 2 

    jmp prime_fact

prime_fact:
    cmp %r10, %rax    # to end function
    jl fact_end

    call fact_print     # where I think it should be printed

    mov %rax, %rsi    # rax = 5, rsi = 5
    add %rdx, %rsi    # rdx = 0, rsi = 5

    cmp $1, %rsi    # if 5 = 1, end function
    jne prime_base    

    jmp fact_end

fact_print:
    mov $.fact_print, %rdi
    mov %r10, %rsi
    xor %rax, %rax
    call printf
    ret

fact_end:
    mov $.fact_end, %rdi
    xor %rax, %rax
    call printf
    ret

prime_end:
    mov $.prime_end, %rdi
    xor %rax, %rax
    call printf
    ret

main:
    mov $10, %rsi    # check 10 ... expect 2 5
    call prime
```

---

When I try to print a prime factorization number, it says

2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
...

I'm sorry. I'm very new. Can you explain why this is printing only 2 infinitely? What do I have to do to print the prime factorization?

Comment: Why do you have all those zero-offset jumps (jump to a label that is the immediate next instruction)?

Answer (score 0):

The caller of `fact_print` assumes that the `eax` register will not be changed, but this is not the case. When `fact_print` returns, `eax` will have the value returned by `printf` (the number of characters that were output).

You'll want to store `eax` somewhere (in a register that is not modified, or on the stack) before calling `fact_print`, then restore it upon return.

Comment: ... or use any of the several call-preserved registers in x86-64 calling conventions, instead of the stack.  [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672)