# 64bit Assembly - Problem with printing out arguments

Tags: linux, assembly, arguments, x86-64

So i was experimenting with printing out arguments that were passed in terminal.

```
%include "OPCODES.asm"
%include "FILE_DESCRIPTORS.asm"
%include "FUNCTIONS.asm"

SECTION .data
    noMsg db "No Arguments Passed!",0
    foundMsg db "Argument Found!",0
SECTION .bss
SECTION .text
global _start
_start:

    POP RCX
    CMP RCX , 1
    JE noArgs
    
    printArgs:
        CMP RCX , 1
        JE finished
        printLn foundMsg
        DEC RCX
        JMP printArgs

noArgs:
    printLn noMsg
    JMP finished
    
finished:
    exit
```

the part where i check whether there are no arguments works , but when there is at least one argument passed it goes in an unlimited loop, and i don't really know why, it decrements the counter and checks whether it is 1.

"exit" & "printLn" are macros defined in FUNCTIONS.asm .

Im working on linux kubuntu and i use NASM for assembly.

Comment: Does `printLn` preserve RCX?  I'm guessing not; single step with a debugger to see.  (If that's the problem, use a call-preserved register like RBX instead).  Where did you get FUNCTIONS.asm?  It's not a standard part of NASM.

Comment: Also note that if your program was started by `execve("your_prog", [NULL], envp)`, your argc will be 0, not 1, so it would be better to use `jbe noArgs` instead of printing "arg found" 2^64 times in that case.

Comment: [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672) / [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) might be relevant, except that `printLn` isn't a function or a system call; it's a macro that has no reason to follow any standard "calling convention".  (Although it must make a system call, so clobbering RCX would be normal if it doesn't specifically preserve it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the help ! i changed RCX to RBX and everything went smooth. also FUNCTION.asm is just a file i made to store my macros like printLn , exit , etc.

Comment: Oh, so you wrote `printLn` yourself?  Not an exact duplicate, but having your own code overwrite your own registers is something you should generally notice with a debugger when single-stepping.