# x64 argument and return value calling convention

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I invoke Clang 12.0.0 with `-Os -march=haswell` to compile the following C program:

```
int bar(int);

int foo(int x) {
  const int b = bar(x);
  if (x || b) {
      return 123;
  }
  return 456;
}
```

The following assembly is generated:

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, edi
        call    bar
        or      eax, ebx
        mov     ecx, 456
        mov     eax, 123
        cmove   eax, ecx
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WsGoM56Ez

As I understand it, the caller of foo sets up x in RAX/EAX. foo then calls bar, which doesn't require modifying RAX/EAX, since x is passed through as unmodified input.

The `or eax, ebx` instruction appears to be comparing the input x with the result of bar. How does that result end up in EBX? What purpose does `mov ebx,edi` serve?

Comment: `x` is passed in via `edi`. `ebx` is a callee-saved register, the `mov ebx, edi` serves the purpose of preserving the value across the `call bar`. The result of `bar(x)` is what is in `eax` at the `or eax, ebx` with `x` still being in `ebx`.

Comment: The `or` combines two values in a bitwise OR operation. After this the destination register is overwritten here. However, the arithmetic status flags are still as set by the `or`. So `cmove` (conditional move, if equal) only writes the new value to its destination if the `or` found both of its inputs to equal zero.

Comment: `or eax, ebx` is implementing `x || b`, it's not comparing anything.

Comment: I think all these misunderstandings stem from a wrong assumption about where the calling convention passes `x`, making this a duplicate.  If not, we can reopen or find more duplicates.  Matt Godbolt's CppCon talk (https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) might be helpful.  (Related: 
 [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) )

Comment: (Also related: [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672) / [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078), as well as [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) which is still a possible duplicate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid you are mistaken:

- the function argument is passed in rdi, as per the [x86-64 System V calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-and-user-space-f).
- register rbx [must not be modified by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672); GCC saves/restores it as required, so it can keep a copy of `x` there across the call to `bar`.
- the function return value is in rax.  (Actually eax; a 32-bit `int` only uses the low half)

You can verify the basics by compiling a function like `int foo(int x){return x;}` - you'll see just a `mov eax, edi`.

Here is a commented version:

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        push    rbx           # save register rbx
        mov     ebx, edi      # save argument `x` in ebx
        call    bar           # a = bar()  (in eax)
        or      eax, ebx      # compute `x | a`, setting FLAGS
        mov     ecx, 456      # prepare 456 for conditional move
        mov     eax, 123      # eax = 123
        cmove   eax, ecx      # if `(x | a) == 0` set eax to 456
        pop     rbx           # restore register rbx
        ret                   # return value is in eax
```

The compiler optimizes `x || b` as `(x | b) != 0` which allows for branchless code generation.

Note that [`mov`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) doesn't modify the FLAGS, unlike most integer ALU instructions.