# Pointer arithmetic with c and Assembly

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, x86

I want to access a specific position on memory using Assembly and C.

I've create the following struct:

```
struct node{
    uint64_t x[5];
    uint64_t y;
    struct node * next;
};
```

Later, I created a object of that type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    uint64_t x[5];
    uint64_t y;
    struct node * next;
};

void foo();

struct node * ptr;

int main(){
    
    struct node* ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->next = NULL;

    foo();

    printf("%lu\n", ptr->y);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, on Assembly, I want to change the value of y.

```
    .section .data
    
    .text
    .globl  foo
    .extern ptr

foo:

    //access ptr->y
    leaq (ptr + 40), %r12
    movq $42, %r12
    
    ret
```

I want %r12 to have the address of ptr->y. I imagined that it would get the correct address, because ptr.x would be first in memory and it weights 8*5 = 40 bytes, however that's not the case.

Comment: @harold it's missing the 'ret' at the end. I guess the correct would be movq $42, 0(%r12), right?

Comment: I suggest to fill the structure with data that is easy to recognize before calling `foo()`. Run your program in a debugger step-by-step and check the register and memory that holds the structure..

Comment: Instead of a global variable it might be better design to pass the pointer as paramter to `foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, choose a different register from `%r12`.  In the x86-64 ABI used on Linux and most other Unix-like systems (which I assume you are using, since that's the main target for the GNU assembler), [`%r12` is a "callee-saved" register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call), which means that when the compiler calls your function `foo`, it expects `%r12` to keep its value.  You could push and pop `%r12` at the start and end of your function, but it's simpler just to choose a different register which is "caller-saved", for which the compiler assumes its value could change.  I'll use `%rax` below.

You need a load from memory to get the value of `ptr` into a register.  Your `leaq` won't do that; it ends up with the *address* of pointer, plus 40, in `%r12`, and does not read from memory.  You instead need a `mov` with a memory source operand.

Then, you need to do a store to actually write to the address that `ptr` points to (plus 40).  Your current `movq` only puts the number 42 into the `%r12` register and doesn't modify memory at all.

Try

```
    .text
    .globl  foo
    .extern ptr

foo:

    movq ptr, %rax  # no $ means this is a load from memory
    movq $42, 40(%rax)
    ret
```

If trying to build a position-independent executable (default for 64-bit Linux), you need rip-relative addressing to access a global variable.  In that case, replace `movq ptr, %rax` by `movq ptr(%rip), %rax`.

---

You have a separate problem in that you declare a local variable named `ptr` in `main`, which shadows the global variable with the same name.  The result of `malloc` is assigned to the local variable, while the global one stays equal to `NULL`.  The function `foo` will access the global one, so it'll dereference NULL and crash.  You should change

```
    struct node* ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

to simply

```
    ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

which does not declare a new variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I didn't notice that I declared struct node on main again. Nice catch! I wanted to put the address of ptr->y on %r12. Is it possible?

Comment: @LuizSantos: You can, but it will take an extra instruction and be less efficient:  `movq ptr, %r12 ; addq $40, %r12 ; movq $42, (%r12)`.  There isn't any instruction that will load a value from memory, do arithmetic on it, and keep it in a register.

Comment: @LuizSantos: BTW, you should *always* use RIP-relative addressing for static variables in 64-bit code, just like a compiler, because that's more efficient.  The only reason not to is when indexing a global array with another register(s), or [when putting a symbol address into a register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register).  `movq ptr, %r12` will work in a non-PIE executable on Linux, though.  (R12 is call-preserved, so the compiler-generated code that calls this will expect R12 to be unmodified, though.)

Comment: In GAS, `.extern ptr` does nothing; that's already the default for undeclared symbols.  I guess it doesn't hurt as documentation, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Good spot with r12 being call preserved.  I updated my code to fix that.