# returning Assembly Function In C Code x86 Compilation on 64 bit linux

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, mixing

**C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int);

int main()

{

    int x = fibonacci(3);

    printf("Fibonacci is : %d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

**Assembly**

```
section .text

global fibonacci

fibonacci:

    push ebp;
    mov ebp, esp;
    ; initialize
    mov dword [prev], 0x00000000;
    mov dword [cur], 0x00000001;
    mov byte [it], 0x01; 
    mov eax, dword [ebp + 8]; // n = 3
    mov byte [n], al;

getfib:

    xor edx,edx;
    mov dl, byte [n];
    cmp byte [it] , dl;
    jg loopend; 
    mov eax,dword [prev];
    add eax, dword [cur];
    mov ebx, dword [cur];
    mov dword [prev], ebx;
    mov dword [cur] , eax;
    inc byte [it];
    jmp getfib;

loopend:

    mov eax, dword [cur];

    pop ebp;

    ret;

section .bss

    it resb 1

    prev resd 1

    cur resd 1

    n resb 1
```

I was trying to run this assembly function in C code and on debugging , i saw that value in variable x in C code is right but there is some error coming when i use the printf function

Need Help on it

Command to compile:

nasm -f elf32 asmcode.asm -o a.o

gcc -ggdb -no-pie -m32 a.o ccode.c -o a.out

Click Below Pictures if they seem blurred

Below is debug before printf execute
[image]

Below is after printf execute
[image]

Comment: Please can you post the full error messages that you are seeing.

Comment: i am not getting compile time errors but runtime and i added them above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not preserve the `ebx` register which is a callee-preserved register.  The `main` function apparently tries to do some `rip`-relative addressing to obtain the address of the format string for `printf` using `ebx` as a base register.  This fails because your code overwrote `ebx`.

To fix this issue, make sure to save all callee-saved registers before you use them and then restore their value on return.  For example, you can do

```
fibonacci:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx ; <---

    ...

    pop ebx ; <---
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i understand the mistake now and program is working now fine

Comment: is there any way we can know before that this is a callee register and we should not change that

Comment: @BhavyaKapoor Refer to the ABI document for the platform you are programming for.  For Linux, a good overview is found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl).  `cdecl` is the convention used on i386 Linux.

Comment: *apparently tries to do some rip-relative addressing* - That's normal these days for `gcc -m32`, remember that most distros build GCC with `-fPIE -pie` on by default.  This unfortunately still applies to `-m32` code where it's much less efficient.

Comment: @fuz: `cdecl` is not the actual name of the i386 System V calling convention.  It happens to work the same as MSVC `cdecl` for basic arg passing and call-preserved registers, but current Linux i386 System V requires maintaining 16-byte stack alignment, unlike `cdecl`.  They also don't 100% agree on how to pass/return structs, e.g. i386 SysV returns 64-bit structs of two int members in memory, but MSVC cdecl returns in EDX:EAX.  https://godbolt.org/z/seaG75svo.

Comment: @BhavyaKapoor: See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls (and user-space functions) on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) for descriptions of the calling conventions and links to the docs.  For x86-64, see [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672).  But really, go read https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf for nice details on how they work, which will hopefully cover any other stuff you didn't realize you need to know.  (And other stuff on https://www.agner.org/optimize

Comment: @PeterCordes I wanted to link the first one at first, but I think it didn't talk about callee saved registers.

Comment: @fuz: Oh right, it only mentions that for system calls.  That Q&A is really over-crowded and messy and should be split up.  (With a link to a separate Q&A about function calls).

Comment: Ok Thank You fuz and Peter Cordes , i will go through these references and would read about cdecl too

Comment: @BhavyaKapoor Have fun!  Do not hesitate to come back with further questions.  You are good at asking questions in comparison with many other beginners.

Comment: @fuz Thank you sir and yep i will mark as resolved

Comment: @fuz can you please also send a link for understanding rip relative addressing which could beginner understandable

Comment: @BhavyaKapoor Sorry, I don't know any good text on the subject.  The idea is that as the load address of the program is not known, it has to compute the addresses of functions by adding the distance from the current address to the contents of the `eip` register.  It's not something you really have to wrangle with as a beginner.  Just compile with `-fno-pie` to get rid of this.

Comment: Note that you will still need to preserve the `ebx` register.  It might be used for other purposes as well.

Comment: @fuz okey , i got things cleared about callee and caller based register and now got an abstract idea of the relative addressing too