# x86_64 nasm read syscall isn't null-terminated

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, stdin

## x86_64 nasm read syscall isn't null-terminated

New to assembly. In fact this is my first hello world program.
OS: Arch Linux (64-bit)

### Logic

I have three functions. `strlen`, `stdin` and `stdout`.
`strlen`:
Find's the length of a string by looping through bytes until it finds a null-byte.

`stdin` and `stdout` just use the read and write syscalls.

First, I ask for the user's input with `stdout` (not important)
Then I create an input prompt using `stdin`
`stdin` puts the input inside the string `rl`
Lastly, `stdout` attempts to print the input.

### The issue

If you recall how `strlen` works. It loops until it finds a null-byte.
However `stdin` doesn't null-terminate it's input.
Therefore when `stdout` goes to find the length of the input it won't stop at the end of the input and will continue collecting garbage until it comes across a null-byte. But by then you will have something looking like this:

```
What is your name?
Logan
Logan
��
   @ @@%)@1+@7L@>a@O@J @V @]▒ @hello.asmstrrlstrlenstrlen_nextstrlen_nullstdinstdoutExitSuccess__bss_start_edata_end.symtab.strtab.shstrtab.text.datam! @ ▒ P
▒       h!b�!'
```

The simple fix should be to just add a null-byte at the end of the string. How could I go about doing this? Also as I said at the beginning, very new to assembly... So your fancy lingo will only intimidate me.

### Full program

```
            global    _start

            section     .data
str:        db          "What is your name?", 10, 0     ; db: Define byte (8 bits)
                                                        ; Declare hw to be "Hello, world!"
                                                        ; 10 = "\n" (newline character)
rl:         db          0

            section     .text
_start:
            mov         rsi,    str
            call        stdout          ; Write to STDOUT
            call        stdin
            call        stdout

            jmp         ExitSuccess     ; Return with exit code 0
strlen:
            push        rsi             ; Save string to stack
strlen_next:
            cmp         [rsi], byte 0   ; Compare char to null byte
            jz          strlen_null     ; Jump if null byte

            inc         rcx             ; Char wasn't null, increment rcx (string length)
            inc         rsi             ; Next char
            jmp         strlen_next     ; Repeat, until we get a null byte
strlen_null:
            pop         rsi             ; Load string from the stack
            ret                         ; Return to call
stdin:
            mov         rax,    0
            mov         rdi,    0
            mov         rsi,    rl
            mov         rdx,    strlen
            syscall
            ret
stdout:
            mov         rax,    1       ; syscall write
            mov         rdi,    1       ; File descriptor STDOUT
            call        strlen          ; String length of rsi
            mov         rdx,    rcx     ; Move strlen of rsi into rdx
            syscall

            ret
ExitSuccess:
            mov         rax,    60      ; syscall exit
            mov         rdi,    0       ; Move exit code into rdi
            syscall
```

Comment: BTW `sys_read` returns the number of bytes that it read

Comment: Right.  And in case you missed it, that's the answer.  If you know how many bytes were read, you can store a zero byte that many bytes into your buffer.

Comment: Great, now how would I go about implementing that? Because if I am being honest. I am just winging it here.

Comment: `mov byte [rsi+rax], 0` after the system call, since the pointer is still in RSI.  At least after checking that RAX is non-negative (because that would indicate an error return like `-EBADF` if the ran your program with stdin closed.)

Comment: I put `mov byte [rsi+rax], 0` after the `syscall` in `stdin`. However I still get the same issue. There is also the possibility that my theory about the buffer not being null-terminated isn't correct...

Comment: But your program has no reason to want a zero-terminated string; the next thing you're doing is a `write` system call to stdout, which takes a pointer and a length.  So `mov rdx, rax`.  Also note that a normal `strlen` clobbers RAX and RDI because it follows the calling convention.  Yours doesn't, so I'd recommend not calling it`strlen`.  Yours is broken since it doesn't zero RCX first, it just increments RCX by the length. (RCX will hold the address of the instruction after the last `syscall` you ran, since that's where `syscall` copies RIP so the kernel will know where to return to.)

Comment: So `write` with a huge length results in your program copying bytes to stdout until it hits an unmapped page; `strace ./a.out` will show you the args you pass to system calls.

Comment: The reason I want a zero-terminated string is because if I want to use that input later on but I have lost the length of the string then I can just find it again using`_strlen` (I renamed as you said)

Answer (score 1):

Two changes had to be made:
Firstly, I needed to fix the `strlen` function. (which I have renamed to `_strlen`)
The issue was that I forgot to set `rcx` to zero before I began the counting,
Lastly, directly after we do the `syscall` in `stdin` we then add a null-byte at the end of the buffer. (`mov byte [rsi+rax-1], 0`)

```
;##################################################################################################################################
;
; hello.asm
;
; 15/09/2023
;
; Logan Seeley
;
; Compiling:
;   Create object file:     $ nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
;   Link object file:       $ ld -m elf_x86_64 hello.o -o hello
;   Execute file:           $ ./hello
;   Print exit code:        $ printf "\n[Process finished with exit code $?]\n"
;
;   All in one command:
;   $ nasm -f elf64 hello.asm; ld -m elf_x86_64 hello.o -o hello; ./hello; printf "\n\n[Process finished with exit code $?]\n"
;
;   TODO:  Use call-preserved registers RBX, RBP, RSP, and R12-R15 for functions instead of using RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9
;           RBX, RBP and RSP should be used for args
;           R12-15 should be used for return values
;
;##################################################################################################################################

            global    _start

            section     .data
prompt:     db          "What is your name?", 10, 0     ; db: Define byte (8 bits)
                                                        ; Declare prompt to be "What is your name?"
                                                        ; 10 = "\n" (newline character)
                                                        ; 0  = null-byte (for zero-termination)
hello:     db         "Hello, ", 0

bufsize     equ         2048
rl:         resb        bufsize

            section     .text
_start:
            mov         rsi,    prompt  ; Move string into rsi to be written to STDOUT
            call        stdout          ; Write to STDOUT
            call        stdin
            mov         rsi,    hello
            call        stdout
            mov         rsi,    rl      ; Move input into rsi
            call        stdout

            jmp         ExitSuccess     ; Return with exit code 0
_strlen:
            xor         rcx,    rcx     ; Move 0 into rcx so we count up from 0
            push        rsi             ; Save string to stack
strlen_next:
            cmp         [rsi], byte 0   ; Compare char to null byte
            jz          strlen_null     ; Jump if null byte

            inc         rcx             ; Char wasn't null, increment rcx (string length)
            inc         rsi             ; Next char
            jmp         strlen_next     ; Repeat, until we get a null byte
strlen_null:
            pop         rsi             ; Load string from the stack
            ret                         ; Return to call
stdin:
            mov         rax,    0
            mov         rdi,    0
            mov         rsi,    rl
            mov         rdx,    _strlen
            syscall
            mov         byte [rsi+rax-1], 0     ; Setting last character of buffer to null-byte
                                                ; Replacing last character instead of concatting,
                                                ; because last character is a newline from user pressing enter
            ret
stdout:
            mov         rax,    1       ; syscall write
            mov         rdi,    1       ; File descriptor STDOUT
            call        _strlen         ; String length of rsi
            mov         rdx,    rcx     ; Move strlen of rsi into rdx
            syscall

            ret
ExitSuccess:
            mov         rax,    60      ; syscall exit
            mov         rdi,    0       ; Move exit code into rdi
            syscall
```

Comment: `rl:         db          0` only reserves space for 1 byte.  You tell the `read` system call to read a number of bytes equal to the address of `_strlen`.  Pick a buffer size and use it, like `bufsize: equ 2048` and `rl: resb bufsize`.  Your code happens to work anyway because there's nothing after it in `.data`, and memory protection has page granularity.

Comment: Also, storing a zero just so you can go look for it later is very inefficient compared to just returning a length and passing it to the next call.  But sure, you *can* do that if you want to have only one global variable and no args or return values, a `char rl[]` buffer you treat as a C string.  And if you want to cut off binary data at the first `0` byte, if the user redirects input from a binary file or pipe.

Comment: Oh wait, it's not avoiding args or return values between functions; `stdout:`  depends on RSI still pointing at the buffer.  So you're basically writing one big `_start` function, but dispatching parts of it using `call`.  This would be less bad design if you had the top-level code at `_start` set up RSI pointing to `rl` instead of having `stdin` do that arbitrarily.

Comment: How would I avoid args and return values between functions? I am new to assembly so I don't know much about common practice and good design,

Comment: You shouldn't avoid that; just like in higher-level programming languages, if you're going to write functions at all, they  *should* communicate via args and return values, not just by having global variables. (The standard function-calling convention is very similar to the system-calling convention, with args in RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9 in that order if you have that many, and return value in RAX.  The call-preserved regs are RBX, RBP, RSP, and R12-R15.  Custom calling conventions like your _strlen are fine in asm as long as you comment them.)

Comment: I commented that your code is written *like* it's trying to avoid passing args and returning values not because that's a good thing but because that's what it looks like, no `mov reg, val` before `call`.  But isn't achieving that since it depends on register values in weird ways across `call`s with no comments to document it, so it's like one big `main` or `_start`.  See also [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672) and [Win64 and Linux-x86\_64 Calling Convention Unused registers modified or not](//stackoverflow.com/q/69484993)

Comment: If you're going to make up a custom calling convention for `_strlen`, you could have it return in RDX where the caller needs the value anyway.  Or like harold pointed out, just return a length from `stdin` and pass it to the next function so you don't need to scan the string.