# x86 asm writes out random letters

Tags: string, assembly, x86, low-level

here is the code with the enviroment
https://replit.com/@DominikDevelopm/testing#main.asm

if i write a longer text, or write text multiple times, it writes out characters that were written earlier.

```
section .bss
    inp resb 16

section .text
    global _start

_start: ; main
  jmp _mainLoop
  call _exit
_mainLoop:
  call _getInp
  mov rax, inp
  call _print
  jmp _mainLoop

_exit:
    mov rax, 60 ; sys ID
    mov rdi, 0 ; exit code
    syscall ; interrupt
_getInp:
    mov rax, 0 ; sys ID
    mov rdi, 0 ; FileDesc
    mov rsi, inp ; buf
    mov rdx, 16  ; len
    syscall ; interrupt
    ret ; return to where called
    
_print:
  push rax
  mov rbx, 0
_printLoop:
  inc rax
  inc rbx
  mov cl, [rax]
  cmp cl, 0
  jne _printLoop
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  pop rsi
  mov rdx, rbx
  syscall
  ret
```

Comment: I hope that replit link was just to share the code so people can see the symptoms; it doesn't seem to include the ability to single-step or set breakpoints.  Using a debugger is pretty nearly essential for learning asm, big waste of time to not use one, so you'll want to use GDB or something on your own machine.  Anyway, see comments on [x86\_64 nasm read syscall isn't null-terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77115934) - your strlen loop is looking for a `0` byte, but nothing puts one at the end of the last `read`'s input.  It returns a length, use that.