# Assembly Code Segmentation Error While Making DFA state machine

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, dfa

I have the following code:

```
.section .data
input_prompt:
.asciz "Enter a string of 0s and 1s: "
invalid_message:
.asciz "ERROR: invalid input\n"
EEPrompt:
.asciz "Input accepted\n"
NotEEPrompt:
.asciz "Input rejected\n"
.section .bss
input:
.byte 0
.byte 0  # stores current character
.section .text
.globl main

main:
# PRINTS INPUT PROMPT
lea input_prompt, %rdi   # point to our input prompt
call puts@PLT           # outputs using PUTS

movl $0, %ebx            # Initialize our state
lea input, %rsi          # points to input buffer
movl $0, %edx            # Initialize edx for conditional moves

read_loop:
# Read each character with call getchar@PLT
call getchar@PLT
# CHECKS FOR NEW LINE
cmpb $0x0A, %al          # If a new line is detected, we are finished.
je input_finalize        # End the loop

# We need to determine if the character we are processing is a '1' or a '0'
sub $0x30, %al           # Convert ASCII to binary: '0' -> 0, '1' -> 1
cmovl %edx, %ebx         # If %al is less than 0, set %ebx to %edx (invalid state)
cmovge %edx, %ebx        # If %al is greater than or equal to 0, set %ebx to %edx

# Store our new and valid input
movb %al, (%rsi)         # Store the character
inc %rsi                # Increment the buffer

# Update the conditional move value for the next iteration
mov %ebx, %edx

# Jump table
jmp *jump_table(,%rbx,8)

jump_table:
.quad ee_state
.quad oe_state
.quad oo_state
.quad eo_state

ee_state:
movl $0, %edx            # EE 
jmp read_loop
oe_state:
movl $1, %edx            # OE
jmp read_loop

oo_state:
movl $2, %edx            # OO 
jmp read_loop

eo_state:
movl $3, %edx            # EO 
jmp read_loop

invalid_input:
# Invalid Input Detected. Terminate the program.
lea invalid_message, %rdi   # point to our invalidity message
call puts@PLT               # outputs using PUTS
jmp exit_with_code

accepted_input:
# Print a message for ACCEPTED input
lea EEPrompt, %rdi           # point to our acceptance message
call puts@PLT               # outputs using PUTS
jmp exit_with_code

rejected_input:
# Print a message for REJECTED input
lea NotEEPrompt, %rdi        # point to the error message
call puts@PLT
jmp exit_with_code

input_finalize:
# Add a newline character to the end of the input
movb $0x0A, (%rsi)

# Now, compare the %eax value to see if we are in EE.
cmpl $0, %edx                # Check if we are in EE.
je accepted_input            # IF SO, print our accepted message and exit
jg rejected_input               # IF NOT, print our rejected message and exit

exit_with_code:
movq $60, %rax               # syscall: exit
xor %rdi, %rdi               # status code: %rdi (0 or 1)
syscall
```

It resembles a DFA system, my program is supposed to calculate if an inputted binary string has an even number of 1's and 0's. However, I keep getting a segmentation fault when run and I'm not sure why. I'd prefer to keep my jump tables, and my getchar/puts statements, so how can I resolve my segmentation error given that?

[image]

Comment: A debugger (like GDB, or there are some GUI debuggers) will tell you which instruction is faulting, and what the fault address was.  Always use that as a first step.  But it looks like you dereference `(%rsi)` after `call getchar`, but RSI is call-clobbered, along with multiple other regs.  So at least that bug is a duplicate of [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672) and [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078)

Comment: Also, instead of having 4 different `mov $imm, %edx` instructions that you reach via conditional branches, it would be less redundant to assemble the index from the low bit of the current and previous character.   e.g. `(last & 1) << 1 | (current & 1)`.  e.g. `shr $1, %al` / `adc %ebx, %ebx` / `and $3, %ebx` to shift the bottom bit of AL into RBX and mask away all but the low 2 bits.

Comment: Also, only use `lea` with a symbol if you're using a register or `%rip`.  e.g. `lea input, %rsi` (8 bytes, with a 32-bit absolute addressing mode) should be `lea input(%rip), %rsi` or `mov $input, %esi`.  [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) .  It works anyway since you're linking with `-no-pie`, but if you're going to use 32-bit absolute addressing, do it with `mov` (5 bytes) not `lea`.  Especially if you're going to bother to write `@PLT` on library functions you call; in a non-PIE the linker will indirect to the PLT for you.