# assembly intel 64 bytes, print loop

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have a problem when I want to print in a loop. My idea was to print the elements, in this case, of the difference of the sets. but when it prints the first element it leaves the loop and the print ends

```
 msjFinal                db "}",10,0
    msjElemento             db "%c ,",0
    msjDiferencia           db "Diferencia entre conjuntos: { ",0

 
    conjuntos_0             dw  ''
    conjuntos_1             dw  '2', '8', '6', '7', '5', '3', '8', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'U', 'Y', 'Q', 'R', 'Q', '0', 'W', 'L'      
    conjuntos_2             dw  '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '1', '9', 'P', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'Z', 'W', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'      
    conjuntos_3             dw  '6', '7', '1', '9', '8', '9', 'L', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'P', 'R', 'X', 'S', '0', 'M', 'N', 'Q', 'Z', '5'      
    conjuntos_4             dw  '1', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', 'A', 'B', 'P', 'O', 'L', 'I', 'S', 'O', '0', 'E', '3', 'N', 'M', 'Z'      
    conjuntos_5             dw  '3', '4', '7', '8', '1', '9', 'N', 'E', 'R', 'O', 'K', 'M', 'V', 'F', 'I', 'A', 'C', 'P', 'D', 'W'      
    conjuntos_6             dw  '5', '3', 'J', '2', 'T', '1', '7', '8', 'X', 'S', 'U', 'Z', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'L', 'P', 'V', 'W', 'Q'      
    
    conjuntos               dq conjuntos_0, conjuntos_1, conjuntos_2, conjuntos_3, conjuntos_4, conjuntos_5, conjuntos_6

diferenciaDeConjuntos:

    mov             rdi,msjDiferencia
    sub             rsp,8
    call            printf
    add             rsp,8

    mov             rcx,[nConjunto1]
    mov             rdi,[conjuntos + rcx * 8]       ; cargo a rdi el 1er conjunto

    mov             rcx,[nConjunto2]           
    mov             rsi,[conjuntos + rcx * 8]       ; cargo a rsi el 2do conjunto

    mov             r11,0                           ; indice para pasar de elemento conjunto1
    mov             r8,0                            ; indice para pasar de elemento conjunto2

diferenciaLoop:
    mov             dx, word[rsi + r8 ]             ; elemento del segundo conjunto

    sub             rsp,8
    call            compararElementosPertenencia    ; salta a funcion de pertenencia
    add             rsp,8
    
    cmp             byte[elementoPertenece],0       ; si es 1 no lo necesito paso de elemento, si no lo agrego
    je              agregarElementoDiferencia
    
    add             r8,2                            ; siguiente elemento

    cmp             r8,40
    je              terminarPrint

    jmp             diferenciaLoop



agregarElementoDiferencia:
    
    mov             word[resultadoElemento],dx    ; agrego el elemento

    mov             rdi,msjElemento
    mov             rsi, [resultadoElemento]
    sub             rsp,8
    call            printf
    add             rsp,8

    add             r8,2

    cmp             r8,40
    jb              diferenciaLoop

    sub             rsp,8
    call            terminarPrint
    add             rsp,8

terminarPrint:

    mov             rdi,msjFinal 
    sub             rsp,8
    call            puts
    add             rsp,8

    sub             rsp,8
    call            quiereSeguirOSalir
    add             rsp,8
    
    ret
```

It should print all the elements of the difference and it only prints the first one

Comment: Ok, so it goes wrong somewhere.  Can you identify the exact point at which it goes wrong?  Basically, we presume it is correct/right up to a point and then doesn't do what you want so can be considered incorrect/wrong.  Where is that point?  Do you know how to find it using single step debugging?  If not, then this is a great time to enhance your debugging skills.

Comment: The point at which it breaks is after printing the first element that it finds that does not belong to the other set, there the r8 should increase by 2 because my elements are two bytes. but I tried to see it in gdb and it gives me -127... it is my first program in assembly I don't understand much

Answer (score 1):

The R8 register is **not** call-preserved (callee-saved). See [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call).

> the r8 should increase by 2 because my elements are two bytes. but I tried to see it in gdb and it gives me -127

At *agregarElementoDiferencia:* you have an invokation of `printf` that is allowed to modify R8, and so there's no telling what will happen in the following code that expects R8 to be intact:

> ```
> add             r8,2
> cmp             r8,40
> jb              diferenciaLoop
> sub             rsp,8
> call            terminarPrint
> add             rsp,8
> ```

With gdb reporting R8 being -127, the `cmp r8,40` instruction is not going to be below (-127 is way **above** 40), and so *terminarPrint* is executed.

Simply use a call-preserved register like RBX instead of R8.