# How to avoid infinite loops in a function call in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, infinite-loop, calling-convention, method-call

I am writing a program in assembly for x86-64 microprocessors in 64-bit mode, and that calls a function `f` in a loop 5 times which in turn calls `puts` in a loop 3 times to display "hello
world".

To assemble the code, I am using `gcc myfile.s -o myfile` and then I run it using `./myfile`.

This is the code:

```
.section .rodata
.LC0:
    .ascii "hello world\0"

.text
.global main
.type main, @function
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl $0, %ecx

main_loop:
    cmpl $5, %ecx
    jge main_end

    call f
    incl %ecx
    jmp main_loop

main_end:
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret

.global f
.type f, @function
f:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl $0, %edx

f_loop:
    cmpl $3, %edx
    jge f_end

    leaq .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call puts
    incl %edx
    jmp f_loop

f_end:
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

The problem is that I am entering an infinite loop and "hello world" is being printed infinitely. What could have gotten wrong? Are the registers for loop counters becoming zero somewhere or is it something else?
I am pretty new to assembly in general and function calls specifically, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RCX and RDX registers are not preserved across calls! See [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call).

You could use RBX instead of RDX:

```
f:
    pushq %rbp
    movq  %rsp, %rbp
    subq  $16, %rsp            ; Space to preserve RBX plus keep stack 16-byte aligned
    movq  %rbx, -8(%rbp)       ; Preserve RBX
    movl  $3, %ebx

f_loop:
    leaq  .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call  puts
    decl  %ebx
    jnz   f_loop

    movq  -8(%rbp), %rbx       ; Restore RBX
    movq  %rbp, %rsp
    popq  %rbp
    ret
```

Modify the *main* in a similar way!

---

Some alternatives as mentioned by @PeterCordes in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932520/how-to-avoid-infinite-loops-in-function-call-in-assembly#comment137394029_77932579):

#### With prologue/epilogue

```
f:
    pushq %rbp
    movq  %rsp, %rbp
    pushq %rbx                 ; (1) Keep stack 16-byte aligned
    pushq %rbx                 ; (2) Preserve RBX
    movl  $3, %ebx

f_loop:
    leaq  .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call  puts
    decl  %ebx
    jnz   f_loop

    popq  %rbx                 ; (2) Restore RBX
    movq  %rbp, %rsp           ; (1) ???
    popq  %rbp
    ret
```

#### Without prologue/epilogue

```
f:
    pushq %rbx                 ; Preserve RBX
    movl  $3, %ebx

f_loop:
    leaq  .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call  puts
    decl  %ebx
    jnz   f_loop

    popq  %rbx                 ; Restore RBX
    ret
```

Comment: You don't need RBP as a frame pointer here, you could have just pushed RBX instead like an optimizing compiler would if you don't force it to use a frame pointer.  Or if you want RBP and RBX, `push %rbx` twice, or `sub $8, %rsp` / `push %rbx` at the start then end with `pop %rbx` and the same `leave`-equivalent teardown of the stack frame for RBP.  I think that would be more idiomatic, closer to what compilers do where they prefer `push`/`pop` for saving/restoring registers.  This is not wrong, though, and about equal speed but larger code-size.

Comment: Except `-8(%rbp)` is the addressing mode syntax.

Comment: @PeterCordes Would it matter for performance to replace `popq %rbx` `movq %rbp, %rsp` by popping the %rbx register twice in a row. In general is it costlier to `popq %rbx` `popq %rbx` than to `popq %rbx` `popq %rax`?

Comment: Since `puts` is slow, the dust will have settled on the stores, so reloading the first store (which would have executed a cycle earlier on CPUs before Ice Lake) doesn't have an advantage.  If both `pop` loads run in the same cycle, the second one will be ready (for our caller to use) just as early as the first.  But if not, the first load could be ready sooner so it's probably better for the caller's use of RBX to be able to start sooner if we make the second load a dummy (into RCX or whatever, or yeah RAX in a void function is fine) and let the RBX value come from the 1st load.