# ARM64 using gas on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, assembly, gnu-assembler, arm64

I've got some assembly functions I've ported to 64-bit ARM, and they work fine on Android, but when I tried to compile the same files in Xcode, I discovered that clang uses a different syntax (different from the official ARM documentation).

I've found some scripts which convert a source file from one format to the other, but this is not the ideal solution (and it seems these scripts don't work when the source files contain preprocessor defines).

Can I simply use gas in Xcode, or configure clang to accept the gas syntax? If not, where is the clang assembler documentation?

**UPDATE - September 2015**

It seems that the issue is solved by XCode 7 (new clang version?): now I can import the assembly source files written for Android, and they are compiled without any change.

Comment: Must the functions be placed inline or are they literally functions in the C sense? I'm getting at whether the assembly functions could be partitioned into a separate compilation unit, as then you could build your assembly with GCC to a static library then merely link to it.

Comment: The functions are defined in an external source file, with extension .S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use my answer as a general guide to writing ARM64 code on Android and iOS. to begin, we'll start with the [volatile and non-volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9268586) registers ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_(A64))):

X0-X7 - arguments and return value (volatile)
X8 = indirect result (struct) location (or temp reg)
X9-X15 = temporary (volatile)
X16-X17 - intro-call-use registers (PLT, Linker) or temp
X18 - platform specific use (TLS)
X19-X28 - callee saved registers (non-volatile)
X29 - frame pointer
X30 - link register (LR)
SP - stack pointer and zero (XZR)
V0-V7, V16-V31 - volatile NEON and FP registers
V8-V15 - callee saved registers (non-volatile, used for temp vars by compilers)

Next up is the assembler directives to correctly create the "segments" for your code:

**Android**
  .cpu generic+fp+simd
  .text
**for each function, add these 3 lines**
  .section  .text.MyFunctionName,"ax",%progbits
  .align 2
  .type MyFunctionName, %function

**iOS** (Nothing really needed except for the align directive)
  .align 2

Declaring public (global) labels

**Android**
 .global MyFunctionName

**iOS**
  .globl _MyFunctionName    **<--notice the leading underscore and different spelling of the global directive**

The next difference is in getting a pointer to static data defined in your source code. For instance, let's say you have a data table and you would like to load register X0 with a pointer to the table.

**Android**

```
  adrp  x0, MyDataTable
  add   x0, x0, #:lo12:MyDataTable
```

**iOS**

```
  adrp  x0,MyDataTable@PAGE
  add   x0,x0,MyDataTable@PAGEOFF
```

Next, NEON syntax. iOS allows the size information to be appended to the instruction mnemonic while Android wants to see the register with the size suffix

**Android**
      ld1 {v0.16b},[x0],#16

**iOS**
      ld1.16b {v0},[x0],#16

**Nested Loops**
In 32-bit ARM code it was typical to push LR on the stack to preserve it for when you need to call a function from within a function. Since NEON instructions are no longer in a co-processor and have been merged into the main instruction set of Aarch64, there's no penalty for moving data back and forth. It's now practical to preserve X30 (LR) in an unused NEON register. For example:

```
  fmov d0,x30   // preserve LR
  <some code which makes function calls>
  fmov x30,d0   // restore LR
```

That's all for now. If someone finds specific cases where there are more differences, I'll add them.

Comment: I'm stuck at the first PRFM: PLDL1KEEP is a perfectly valid token for Android, but Xcode doesn't like it

Comment: I've got the same issue; I can't find a working prefetch syntax for iOS.

Comment: Apparently, it's only case-sensitive. pldl1keep in lower case is ok.

Comment: Ok, my specific problem is solved. Still, I can't find any document describing the syntax for the clang assembler. Mille grazie, caro.

Comment: Its pretty old, and not clang specific: "OS X Assembler Reference", https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/000-Introduction/introduction.html and yeah, its pretty old, but the Clang team told me it was still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck. The Libav team supports a tool that accepts gas syntax and outputs assembler for Apple's assembler. You can find the tool here: https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor/blob/master/gas-preprocessor.pl

Comment: This is the script I couldn't get to work, it seems it can only handle assembly source files without preprocessor macros,