# Is it not neccessary to push EAX in this code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I am new to assembly, and when I studied on the internet, I found the following code, but I don't know why `push eax` is not written before `mov eax, [ebp+8]`.

```
; char* removerng(char* s, char a, char b)
; removes (in place) characters from a to b in string s
    section .text
    global  removerng
removerng:
    ; prologue
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ebx ;<- ebx instead of eax?
    push    esi
    push    edi

    ; body <- we don't need eax?
    mov eax, [ebp+8]; load string into return address
    mov esi, [ebp+8]; last char checked
    mov edi, [ebp+8]; last char placed

loop:
    mov bh, [esi]; current char
    inc esi
    test    bh, bh; test for end of string
    jz  fin
    cmp bh, [ebp+12] 
    jl  keep
    cmp bh, [ebp+16]
    jg  keep
    jmp loop

keep:
    mov [edi], bh
    inc edi
    jmp loop

fin:
    mov [edi], bh

    ;epilogue
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Does this mean we can use both `push ebx` and `push eax` Could any one help me?

Comment: EAX is call-clobbered, EBX is call-preserved (like ESI and EDI).  (And the function uses BH for no reason, so it has to save / restore EBX even though EDX and ECX are still unused.)  It returns in EAX, so it certainly doesn't need to save and restore the caller's value!

Comment: [How to understand volatile and non-volatile registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32002157/327083)

Comment: [Does it matter which registers you use when writing assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59869218/327083)

Comment: Note that `EAX` is often used for the return value of the function, and this is what the comment appears to be saying: `mov eax, [ebp+8]; load string into return address`.

Comment: [What's the advantage of having nonvolatile registers in a calling convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10392895/327083)

Comment: This is a pretty clunky example.  Specifically, never write code like `jg  keep` / `jmp loop` / `keep:`.  That could just be a `jng loop` with fall-through to the next block.  And don't use high-8-bit registers for no reason; AH/BH/CH/DH are slower than normal registers on some CPUs.

Comment: There are also various optimizations it could make, e.g. a range-check with sub / cmp / ja instead of two separate compare and branch.  And keeping the values to compare against in registers instead of reloading from the stack for every char in the string.  The in-place filtering algorithm is good, though, although could be optimized with a read-only scan for the first character to remove.