# C++20 coroutines and C++26 fibers: performance of calls and of context switches

Tags: c++, coroutine, fibers

I have been reading this paper about the addition of `fiber_context` to the C++ standard library: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2024/p0876r15.pdf. I have been researching about (stackless) coroutines and stackful coroutines (aka fibers), and I would like to know what are the performance considerations between both in terms of:

**NOTE:** I'm assuming the current boost::fiber library is representative enough of whatever is finally added to future C++ standards.

- Calling/creating: I know that creating a coroutine implies creating a single frame in the heap (whose size is known at compile-time), while creating a fiber implies creating a full stack (with implies deciding an allocator strategy for the stack, decision that is on the user). But besides the stack, what else is needed for creating a coroutine and a fiber respectively?
- Context switch: that's where I'm not clear about the performance adventages of coroutines versus fibers. In my mind both cases implies some sort of jump plus saving some registers, which doesn't look like a big difference. Is there such a difference between both? What else must be done to context switch between coroutines and fibers respectively, or why they need to store a different set of registers (if that's the case)?

I understand assembly a bit so you can talk in terms of the specific registers that requires to be stored, where there are stored, why, etc. I can bear low-level stuff. If you can do some estimate in terms of CPU-cycles (specially for context-switches), that would be interesting to know too.

To help you be more specific, I'm happy with understanding the "implementation details" for Linux x86-64 only (and I'm also interested to know if there's aspects of implementing fibers that requires OS-support).

Comment: The implementation of each is completely different. With coroutines, the compiler turns your functions into state machines; each time you 'co_await' the function actually saves where it got to, then when you resume it, it actually calls the function again and checks where it left off. Fibers are literally just threads where you control the scheduling instead of the OS.

Comment: When you resume a fiber, the "where it left off" information must also be stored, otherwise fibers resumption will always start from the beginning. Still, similar behaviour.

Comment: It's saved in the same way as threads; the function doesn't return; its stack frame stays on the fiber's stack. A coroutine basically saves a "which co_await did I just do" number, and then returns from the function.

Comment: I still don't see why the differences you are describing are significative in terms of performance. Whatever it's a state machine or a program counter stored somewhere, it's still a jump and a variable somewhere storing where to jump to, and both execution contexts (frame with all the local variables of a coroutine, or stack of frames of a fiber) are in the heap.

Comment: the most obvious tangible differences related to that are that only the outer function of a coroutine can pause (because it has no stack), and it uses less memory when it's not running (because it has no stack) and it doesn't need operating system support (because it's a compiler feature).

Comment: Looking at `boost::fiber` implementation, fiber context switching seems to require storing/restoring *all* [non-volatile registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002157/how-to-understand-volatile-and-non-volatile-registers). It's more expensive than just modifying `rip` and `rsp` on win/linux x64 ABIs. I don't think entering/yielding a coroutine requires that. If a future `std::fiber` wants to support something like `std::this_fiber::yield()` (similar to `this_thread`) from any normal function, I don't see how systematic storing/restoring of non-volatile register can be avoided.

Comment: @ABu Fiber on windows can also have some additional overhead. On windows, this means modifying some global state, as stack-switching cannot simply be done by setting RSP (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77895587/replacing-the-call-stack-of-an-application). Whether or not that is significant is another issue, of course.