# Why is ecx being filled with eax value in MASM?

Tags: x86, masm, calling-convention

This is a simple Hello World code I copied from someone.

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall
 STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE EQU -11  ; std output device

 ;////
; Function prototypes

 GetStdHandle PROTO, nStdHandle: DWORD 
 WriteConsoleA PROTO, handle: DWORD, lpBuffer:PTR BYTE, nNumberOfBytesToWrite:DWORD, lpNumberOfBytesWritten:PTR DWORD, lpReserved:DWORD
 ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD 

 ;////
 .data

 consoleOutHandle dd ? 
 bytesWritten dd ? 
 message db "Hello darkness my old friend",13,10
 lmessage equ $-message

 ;////
 .code

 main PROC
  INVOKE GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
  mov consoleOutHandle, eax 
  mov edx, offset message 
  pushad    
  mov eax, lmessage
  INVOKE WriteConsoleA, consoleOutHandle, edx, eax, offset bytesWritten, 0
  popad
  INVOKE ExitProcess, 0 
 main ENDP

END main
```

I wondered what the pushad and popad were for, so I removed them.

This is register data before and after `WriteConsoleA` is invoked:

```
Before: EAX = 00000014 EBX = 00B1A000 ECX = 008C1005 EDX = 008C4008 ESI = 008C1005 EDI = 008C1005 EIP = 008C1026 ESP = 0081FCE8 EBP = 0081FCF4 EFL = 00000213 

After:  EAX = 00000001 EBX = 00B1A000 ECX = 00000014 EDX = 008C4004 ESI = 008C1005 EDI = 008C1005 EIP = 008C103A ESP = 0081FCE8 EBP = 0081FCF4 EFL = 00000202
```

I looked up the msdn page for the function but couldn't find anything about it.

Is it the function doing this? Do all functions behave like this?

Comment: Functions using the `stdcall` calling convention (e.g. `WriteConsoleA`) are allowed to modify registers `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` without restoring them before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pushad` instruction pushes all the general purpose registers on to the stack so they can later be restored (with, surprisingly enough, `popad`). Without that, a function which modifies registers without itself saving them first, may well leave you in an undesirable state.

In the case of Windows API calls, the [stdcall calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) is used (as per the `.MODEL` directive at the top of your code), which states in part:

> Registers `EAX`, `ECX`, and `EDX` are designated for use within the function. Return values are stored in the `EAX` register.

That means those registers may not be preserved in the call. So, if you want to guarantee they retain their original values, you need to do that yourself, either with `pushad ... popad` or the longer but more targeted:

```
push eax
push ecx
push edx

; call function

pop edx
pop ecx
pop eax
```

Whether that's *necessary* in this very simple example (where you just immediately exit the process after the `WriteConsole` call), I can't say for sure. However, it's often prudent to protect yourself from the undesirable effects of functions that you call.

Comment: So basically just push and pop when calling a function so I don't have to care what happens to the registers? Also the question was about registers, not push and pop. Don't make me be sad ;(

Comment: @PupperGump: usually you just let function calls clobber ECX and EDX (and EAX if that's not a return value).  Doing otherwise would mean cluttering up your code with huge amounts of push/pop.  If you're using Irvine32, note that its functions use a special calling convention where all the registers (except a return value if any) are call-preserved.  So pick other registers for values that need to survive across calls, and EAX/ECX/EDX for "temporaries", e.g. preparing args or stuff you store to memory anyway.  ([What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078))