# Push and pop interfering with ret instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I wrote a simple recursive print function in x86 assembly, however, I noticed that all the instructions after `call print` never get executed, after scratching my head over it, I figured that if I remove `push ax, pop ax` everything works fine, is there something I miss about the stack?

Here is the code:

```
print:
    push ax
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [bx+si]
    inc si
    cmp al, 0x00
    int 0x10
    jne print
    mov al, 0x0d
    int 0x10
    mov si,0
    pop ax
    ret
```

it's a simple recursive function with the base condition of the null character, the parameter is bx, while the counter is SI.

Comment: That's not recursion because you do not `call` your function. It's a loop. And you have a `push ax` in the loop so it will push multiple things and then you only pop one thing. Thus, you unbalance the stack. You also have the `int 0x10` in the wrong place between the `cmp` and the `jne`.

Comment: Yes. This is correct behavior. For every `push` there has to be a `pop` (generally speaking). If your loop has more pushes than pops, the `ret` returns to another address, because both use the same stack.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I am just a beginner in it, so I don't know how to do a conditional call after ```cmp```, can you please help me?
And I assumed that the function is recursive that's why I put ```int 0x10``` before the jump statement, but how can I print it in an iterative way?
I should pop every time before the jump statement?
That seems way too inefficient, is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you need this to be recursive? Also even if you need it to be recursive, why do you need to save `ax`?

Comment: I've just started assembly, so I need to learn these basics like recursion, stack, loops functions, etc...

Comment: And about ax, it's just that I want to keep the code clean, to make the function have as little interference as possible, since it's part of a bootsector.

Comment: recursion is not the first thing on the basics list, it is not on the basics list.   so try basics first.

Comment: I've used your tips and fixed the code (made it iterative), I will post the fixed code in no time! Thank your for saving me :D

Comment: Once you have the basics, then recursion is automatic as to how it works it is no different than calling any other function.

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to use ```call function``` after a cmp instruction instead of using jmp, is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Brief answer as to the stack: After `push ax` add a label `.loop:` (leading dot means local label in NASM) and jump to it using `jne .loop` instead.

Comment: Indeed there is no conditional call instruction.  So instead you use a conditional jump with the opposite sense to jump over the call if you don't want it.  `cmp al, 0x00` / `je past_call` / `call print` / `past_call:  ;rest of code`

Comment: *keep the code clean, to make the function have as little interference as possible, since it's part of a bootsector.* - A boot sector is at most 510 bytes of code.  That's small enough to just use comments on each function to specify which registers it does/doesn't modify.  If you want all your functions to have a common calling convention, it's a good idea for that convention to let AX and DX (and maybe CX) be call-clobbered, so loops that want to call functions can keep their data in any other register if they want it to survive.

Comment: Filling all your functions with push/pop of everything isn't "clean".  See also [call-preserved vs. call-clobbered registers in a calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078).  But anyway, yeah your answer at least keeps the push/pop out of the loop, which doesn't help for code-size but is much better for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the kind folk in the comment section I was able to figure out a way to do it iteratively.

```
print:
    push ax
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [bx+si]
    inc si
    cmp al, 0x00
    int 0x10
    pop ax
    jne print
    push ax
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0d
    int 0x10
    xor si,si
    pop ax
    ret
```

Very inefficient and hacky, but hey it works!

Edit:

I used ECM's tip and here is a more efficient implementation:

```
print:
    push ax
    push si
    .loop:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, [bx+si]
    inc si
    cmp al, 0x00
    int 0x10
    jne .loop
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, 0x0d
    int 0x10
    pop si
    pop ax
    ret
```

It's way cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: Your first version zeros SI for no apparent reason, instead of returning the end of the string as a bonus return value that a caller could use to find out how many bytes were printed.  Is the caller supposed to have zeroed SI for you?  You don't initialize it.  You could just save/restore BX, and `inc bx` to increment a pointer.  (Or to optimize for code size, use `cld` outside the loop, and have the caller pass a pointer in SI so you can use `lodsb` to load AL and increment SI.)

Comment: TL:DR: normally a function takes a pointer arg as one register, not as "DS: BX+SI" being a pointer to the characters.  Also, you can set AH once outside the loop: `int 0x10 / ah=0x0e` doesn't modify AH or AL.  You already depend on it not modifying FLAGS! (Normally you'd put cmp next to jne.  And normally you'd want to not actually print the terminating `0` byte.  e.g. put the load / cmp/jne at the bottom, and print at the top.  You can enter the loop with a `jmp` to the load + loop condition.  See [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47783926))