# Why does my string-print function print extra garbage / file contents after the C string I pass it?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I decided to make a function that prints a string in the EAX register to the console, works from a part by displaying a message first, then something

Code (NASM) :

```
newLine equ 0xa

section .data
    msg db "Hello world!", newLine, 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, msg
    call printf
    call exit

printf:
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx 
    push edx 

    mov ecx, eax
    call lenFind
    mov edx, eax
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    int 0x80

    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax 
    ret

lenFind:
    push edx
    mov edx, 0
    .find:
        cmp [eax+edx], byte 0
        je .close
        inc edx
        jmp .find
    .close:
        pop edx
        ret

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
.shstrtab.text.data
                   �J�
```

idk what it could be, but most likely the problem is that I'm using 32 bit registers

Comment: It looks like your call to `lenFind` expects that it will return the string's length in `eax`.  But if you read what you wrote in `lenFind`, it doesn't.  It doesn't modify `eax` at all, so it still contains the pointer to `msg` when it returns.  It would have the correct length in `edx` when the loop exits, but you discard that value with `pop edx` instead of doing anything useful with it.  I think you want a `mov eax, edx` just before the `pop edx`.

Comment: Looks like all that saving and restoring or registers is mostly making things harder.  Normal calling conventions allow functions to trash ECX and EDX without saving/restoring.  (As well as EAX if it's not a return value).  These are called ["call clobbered" registers, as opposed to "call preserved"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *lenFind* does not return any result!
The length is calculated in the `EDX` register but you have restored that from the stack. However the calling program seems to expect the length to be in the `EAX` register:

```
lenFind:
    push edx
    mov edx, 0
    .find:
        cmp [eax+edx], byte 0
        je .close
        inc edx
        jmp .find
    .close:
        MOV EAX, EDX   <<< Add this line
        pop edx
        ret
```

Comment: It does return a result, the original EAX.  Which is a pointer, thus a large integer.  Thus the whole rest of the page (or contiguous range of page mappings) gets written to stdout, because Linux `write` doesn't check later page permissions before starting to copy readable data to the fd.  You only get `-EFAULT` if the first page is unreadable, even with a huge size that extends into unmapped pages.