# How to preserve the register I touch?

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention

This assignment is "Create an HLA Assembly language program that prompts for three integers from the user.  Create and call a function that returns in DX the value of the parameter that is the smallest of the three.  In order to receive full credit, after returning back to the caller, your function should not change the value of any register other than DX"

My professor said "My Code Is Not Preserving The Registers It Touches."
I do not know how to do it.
Could anyone help?
Is it about push and pop?

```
program Smallest_Number;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );


static
value1 : int16;
value2 : int16;
value3 : int16;

procedure smallest( var value1 : int16; var value2 : int16; var value3 : int16 ); @nodisplay; @noframe; 

static
dReturnAddress : dword;

begin smallest;

pop( dReturnAddress ); 
pop( AX ); 
pop( BX );
pop( CX ); 
push( dReturnAddress );

mov(AX, DX);  
cmp(DX, BX);    
jl check_1;        
mov(BX, DX);   

check_1:
cmp (DX, CX);   
jl end_smallest;   
jmp update_1;     


update_1:
mov (CX, DX);   
jmp end_smallest; 

end_smallest:
stdout.put( "The smallest value is " );
stdout.puti16( DX );

ret( ) ;
end smallest;



begin Smallest_Number;


stdout.put( "Provide value1:" );
stdin.get(value1);
stdout.put( "Provide value2:" );
stdin.get(value2);
stdout.put( "Provide value3:" );
stdin.get(value3);

mov(value1,AX);
mov(value2,BX);
mov(value3,CX);


push(CX);
push(BX);
push(AX);

call smallest;

end Smallest_Number;
```

I have no idea how to do it

Comment: See [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9268586) re: the concept of a call-preserved register, and what that means from the callee's perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My professor said "My Code Is Not Preserving The Registers It Touches." I do not know how to do it. Could anyone help? Is it about push and pop?

Yes! Given this is an assignment, I won't make changes to your code, but I believe that's what your teacher means by "preserving registers it touches."

Something that might benefit you to read on are [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). I believe ABI's have that mostly standardized nowadays, but there's still plenty around to choose from.

Doing my best to help you find your way, consider the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0;

void my_cool_function (int b) {
  a += b + 1;
}

int main () {
  int a;
  a = 0;
  printf("%d", a);


  int b;
  b = 1;
  my_cool_function(b);

  printf("%d", a);
}
```

As you may already know, the `a` variable inside `main` is completely different from the `a` global variable due to scoping rules.
An interesting question would be: could we make it behave the same if these were registers? That is, if `a` in the program above wasn't an abstract container, but rather the name of a register.

Were that the case, the program could behave differently, right? But we can definitely avoid that case somewhat similarly to what is done to variables with the same name. I'll use this uncool sum as a simpler case-study:

```c
int my_uncool_sum (int b, int c) {
  return b + c + 1;
}
```

I've compiled it on my arm machine with zero optimizations so the compiler doesn't get in the way. Here is the disassembly dump that I got:

```
[0x0] <+0>:   sub    sp, sp, #0x10
[0x4] <+4>:   str    w0, [sp, #0xc]
[0x8] <+8>:   str    w1, [sp, #0x8]
[0xc] <+12>:  ldr    w8, [sp, #0xc]
[0x10] <+16>: ldr    w9, [sp, #0x8]
[0x14] <+20>: add    w8, w8, w9
[0x18] <+24>: add    w0, w8, #0x1
[0x1c] <+28>: add    sp, sp, #0x10
[0x20] <+32>: ret
```

In this architecture, ints are 4 bytes long and the destination register is always the instruction's first argument. Knowing that, there's a symmetry between the first instruction `sub sp, sp, 0x10` and the penultimate instruction `add sp, sp, 0x10`, right? The register being used there is the Stack Pointer register and that value, `0x10` is subtracting and adding just enough bytes to fit two integers (for this architecture, 8 bytes)<sup>1</sup>. Remember: the stack grows from high address to low address.

Similar to your code, this function is also executing a kind of pop instruction to get its arguments. For you, that was, e.g., `pop( AX );`. That pop instruction gets a value from the stack and puts it into the register `AX`. What was there before? Anyway, let's keep going.

ARM doesn't allow you to do direct addressing, so a little dance is necessary. First, we get the address of what we want: `str w0, [sp, #0xc]`. `w0` know holds the address of our first parameter.

Then, we get the actual value that memory location points to: `ldr w8, [sp, #0xc]` (the compiler chose not to use `w0` for some reason). `w8` now holds the value of our first parameter. The same process happens for the pair of register `w1` and `w9` for the second argument. We sum them together and increment the Stack Pointer before returning.

One last thing is missing: what does it look like to call this function?
The next snippet is the entire module with definition and a call to the function `my_uncool_sum`:

```
int my_uncool_sum (int b, int c) {
  return b + c + 1;
}

int uncool_sum_usage() {
  volatile register int busy = 0xFFF;
  return busy + my_uncool_sum(1, 2);
}
```

Note that I'm being annoying on `uncool_sum_usage` and asking 4095,`0xFFF` in hex, to be kept around in a register. Here is the disassembly of `uncool_sum_usage`:

```
[0x24] <+0>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x20
[0x28] <+4>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
[0x2c] <+8>:  add    x29, sp, #0x10
[0x30] <+12>: mov    w8, #0xfff
[0x34] <+16>: stur   w8, [x29, #-0x4]
[0x38] <+20>: ldur   w8, [x29, #-0x4]
[0x3c] <+24>: str    w8, [sp, #0x8]
[0x40] <+28>: mov    w0, #0x1
[0x44] <+32>: mov    w1, #0x2
[0x48] <+36>: bl     0x48                      ; <+36> at main.c:7:17
[0x4c] <+40>: ldr    w8, [sp, #0x8]
[0x50] <+44>: add    w0, w8, w0
[0x54] <+48>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x10]
[0x58] <+52>: add    sp, sp, #0x20
[0x5c] <+56>: ret
```

As the fourth instruction tells us, `0xfff` was right there on `w8`. It is followed a `stur` (store register) instruction. That `stur` is using `x29 - 0x4`. `x29` is another general-purpose register and `0x4`, once again, is just enough space for an int<sup>2</sup>. Note that `x29` was recently seen with the Stack Pointer on the third instruction `add x29, sp, #0x10`<sup>3</sup>. After calling the function, we need `0xFFF` back in order to return, and we get it using the Stack Pointer yet again `ldr w8, [sp, #0x8]`.

`0xFFF` was saved and restored even though we made a function call that could've altered our registers. Calling conventions are crucial to have this behavior be consistent. It might help you out to wonder how is the stack significant for function calling? How was it used during this example and what's the relation that it has with calling conventions? How can we make sure we're retaining previous information when jumping to code that might mess however it wants with registers?

Last note: in case you wish to replicate in another architecture (maybe using a different convention?), code was compiled with `-stc=c99 -O0 -g`. `lldb` was used to get the disassembly. If the object file is named `a.out` (the default), you can get the disassembly by running `lldb a.out` and send `disassemble -n uncool_sum_usage` to get the disassembly for the function.

<sup>1</sup> In this architecture, addresses are 64 bit wide. Note that the registers in use are prefixed with `w`, e.g., `W0`. This means they are being using in a 32 bit wide mode, so the top 32 bits are being ignored. Because we're using the Stack Pointer to reference *addresses* rather than *values*, we need enough space for two addresses. A 64 bit address is the same as 8 bytes. One address for each means we need 16 bytes, or, `0x10` in hex.

<sup>2</sup> This time, we're talking about the size of the value rather than the address. The `stur` instruction here is using the value contained within the `busy` variable, namely, `0xFFF`.

<sup>3</sup> Not completely related to the problem at hand, but I figured it would be useful to showcase what's happening here as well. Without giving out too much, the second instruction can be seen as a store for `x29` and `x30`. The following instruction, `add x29, sp, 0x10` is similar to the one we've seen before: `x29` is holding the address `SP + 10` (higher address than `SP`). The sequence starting with `mov w8, #0xfff` and ending with `ldur w8, [x29, #-0x4]` is probably a consequence of disabling optimization. The end result is that `w8` will be holing the value `0xFFF`. It only matters for the next instruction, `str w8, [sp, #0x8]`, which will keep that value safe until we restore it again with `w8, [sp, #0x8]`

Comment: Just for the record, this is AArch64 assembly (from clang, it appears; GCC uses pre/post-increment addressing with `stp` to push/pop even in debug builds: https://godbolt.org/z/qoG7or47G).  The question is using x86, with some really nasty code that actually pops the return address off the stack into a global variable, before popping the args from the stack.

Comment: Your AArch64 asm is totally different because the standard calling convention passes them in registers, so your debug build first spills them with `str` and then reloads for the statement that uses them ([Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53366394)).  And the return address is in a different register, not the stack.  `ldr    w8, [sp, #0xc]` is not a pop, it's like x86 `mov ecx, [esp + 0xc]` for random access to stack memory, which is how you should normally access stack args and locals.

Comment: In `uncool_sum_usage`, `x29` is getting used as a frame pointer, like how x86 code traditionally would use EBP with `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp` and then address into the function's stack frame relative to EBP.  In 16-bit x86 code, there was no `[sp + constant]` addressing mode, so the only convenient way to access stack space was relative to BP, not the stack pointer directly.  These days, compilers only set up a frame pointer in debug builds or functions that use a VLA or otherwise need to restore the stack pointer later.

Comment: That makes sense! TBH, halfway through writing my response I was considering switching my examples to x86, but chose to keep going in order to give the feeling of what's happening regardless of specific architecture details.
I was avoiding using the terms _the stack_ and _frame pointer_ to encourage the student's research. But that makes absolute perfect sense, @PeterCordes