# why this MIPS code doesn't print out results on the console?

Tags: loops, recursion, sum, mips

i have to calculate sum from 1 to n and print out the both result on the console.
but when i execute this code i can't see the result of sum
can you rewrite the code and explain what is the problem in this code?

```
.data
    integer:    .asciiz "\nEnter a positive integer: 
    result_1:   .asciiz "(Iterative)Sum from 1 to n: "
    result_2:   .asciiz "\n(Recursive)Sum from 1 to n: "
    newline:    .asciiz "\n"

.text
    main:
    
        # Print the prompt and read a positive integer from the console
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, integer
        syscall

        read_input:
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            move $t0, $v0   # Store n in $t0

            # Calculate the sum iteratively
            li $t1, 0   # Initialize sum to 0
            li $t2, 1   # Initialize the counter to 1

            loop_iterative:
                add $t1, $t1, $t2   # Add counter to sum
                addi $t2, $t2, 1     # Increment the counter

                # Check if the counter is less than or equal to n
                ble $t2, $t0, loop_iterative
                
            # Call the recursive function to calculate the sum 
            move $a0, $t0
            jal calculate_sum
            
            move $t3, $v0  # Save the result from the recursive call

            # Print a newline
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, newline
            syscall
                    
            # Print the result_1
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, result_1
            syscall

            move $a0, $t1
            li $v0, 1
            syscall
            
            # Print the result_2
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, result_2
            syscall

            move $a0, $t3  # Use the result from the recursive call
            li $v0, 1
            syscall

            # Print a newline
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, newline
            syscall

            # Exit the program
            li $v0, 10
            syscall
            
    calculate_sum:
        # Recursive function to calculate the sum
        # Input: $a0 - n
        # Output: $v0 - sum
        
        # if n <= 1, return 1
        blez $a0, calculate_sum_base
        li $v0, 0
        
        # Save the original $a0
        move $t4, $a0

        # Recursive case: call calculate_sum with n - 1
        addi $t4, $t4, -1
        move $a0, $t4
        jal calculate_sum

        # Add n to the result from the recursive call
        add $v0, $v0, $t4

        # Restore the original $a0
        move $a0, $t4

        jr $ra

    calculate_sum_base:
        li $v0, 1
        jr $ra
```

Comment: Your recursive procedure does not use the stack; thus, it is in error.

Answer (score 0):

your main error on this code is that you did not take into consideration the calle-saving and caller-saving convention which is part of the MIPS assembly language, therefore, a conceptual error.

Looking into your code, you were exiting the program once jr $ra on your recursive function because you did not save $ra into the stack.

> Overall, by convention, all t registers must be saved before entering
> any function and s registers must be saved within a function in order
> to not lose any data.

Read more about this convention on [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers)

Here is a simplified and efficient solution to your code which now respects both callee and caller-saving conventions:

```
.data
    integer:    .asciiz "\nEnter a positive integer: "
    result_1:   .asciiz "(Iterative)Sum from 1 to n: "
    result_2:   .asciiz "\n(Recursive)Sum from 1 to n: "
    newline:    .asciiz "\n"

.text
    main:
        addi $sp, $sp, -4   # Allocate space on the stack for $ra
        sw $ra, 0($sp)      # Save $ra on the stack
        # Print the prompt and read a positive integer from the console
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, integer
        syscall

        read_input:
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            move $t0, $v0   # Store n in $t0

            # Calculate the sum iteratively
            li $t1, 0   # Initialize sum to 0
            li $t2, 1   # Initialize the counter to 1

            loop_iterative:
                add $t1, $t1, $t2   # Add counter to sum
                addi $t2, $t2, 1     # Increment the counter

                # Check if the counter is less than or equal to n
                ble $t2, $t0, loop_iterative
                
            # Call the recursive function to calculate the sum 
            move $a0, $t0
            jal calculate_sum
            
            move $t3, $v0  # Save the result from the recursive call

            # Print a newline
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, newline
            syscall
                    
            # Print the result_1
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, result_1
            syscall

            move $a0, $t1
            li $v0, 1
            syscall
            
            # Print the result_2
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, result_2
            syscall

            move $a0, $t3  # Use the result from the recursive call
            li $v0, 1
            syscall

            # Print a newline
            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, newline
            syscall

            # Exit the program
            lw $ra, 0($sp)
            addi $sp, $sp, 4
            jr $ra
            
    calculate_sum:
        # Recursive function to calculate the sum
        # Input: $a0 - n
        # Output: $v0 - sum
        addi $sp, $sp, -8   # Allocate space on the stack for $ra
        sw $ra, 0($sp)      # Save $ra on the stack
        sw $s0, 4($sp)      # Save n on the stack

        # Check if n is less than or equal to 1
        ble $a0, 1, base_case

        # Calculate the sum recursively
        move $s0, $a0       # Save n in $s0
        addi $a0, $a0, -1   # Decrement n
        jal calculate_sum   # Call the recursive function
        move $a0, $s0       # Restore n from $s0
        add $v0, $v0, $a0   # Add n to the result from the recursive call

        j end

    base_case:
        li $v0, 1   # Return 1
        j end
    end:
        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        lw $s0, 4($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 8
        jr $ra
```