# Segmentation fault for ldrb w10, [x9, 0]

Tags: arm

```
                    .section .data
input_prompt :      .asciz "Please enter a string: \n"
input_format:       .asciz "%[^\n]"
output_format:      .asciz "%c"
new_line_format:    .ascii "\n"

                    .section .text
                    .global main
main:
                    # set i = 0
                    add x19, xzr, xzr
                    # print string
                    ldr x0, = input_prompt
                    bl printf

                    sub sp, sp, 16

                    ldr x0, = input_format
                    mov x1, sp
                    bl scanf

                    mov x0, sp
                    bl revstr

                    add sp, sp, 16

#========================================

revstr:
                    sub sp, sp, 16
                    str lr, [sp, 0]
                    # get string[i]
                    # i=0 first char i = size last char
                    add x9, x19, x0
                    ldrb w10, [x9]
                    strb w10, [sp, 8]
                    # print inorder
                    mov w1, w10
                    ldr x0, =output_format
                    bl printf

                    # if w10 is '\0'(ASCII #10)
                    cbz w10, ret

                    add x19, x19, 1
                    bl revstr

                    # lr start
                    ldr w1, [sp, 8]
                    ldr x0, =output_format
                    bl printf

#========================================

ret:
                    ldr lr, [sp, 0]
                    add sp, sp, 8
                    br lr




                    # branch to this label on program completion
exit:
                    mov x0, 0
                    mov x8, 93
                    svc 0
                    ret
```

I am trying to reverse input string, but if I run the code it said "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation `fault.revstr()` at `pa2.s:37 ldrb w10, [x9,0]` Why do I get this segmentation fault?
What do I need to fix?
Also I am not sure that during printing out reverse string's character, do I need to add sp by 16 every time ?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you confirm you are trying to achieve your goal using recursion ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Comment: Slightly modified the indentation, and replaced x30 by its alias, lr. Please advise if you think I modified the code by mistake. Working on debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I am not an expert in Aarch64 assembly programming.
I looked at, built and debugged your program, and it seems not to be compliant with [Procedure Call Standard for the Arm® 64-bit Architecture (AArch64)](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/main/aapcs64/aapcs64.rst) standard.

For example, GDB complains about a corrupted stack at the beginning of your program:

```
disassemble 0x0000000000400658, 0x00000000004006c0 + 4

=> 0x0000000000400658 <main+0>:     add x19, xzr, xzr
   0x000000000040065c <main+4>:     ldr x0, 0x4006d8 <exit+20>
   0x0000000000400660 <main+8>:     bl  0x401420 <__printf>
   0x0000000000400664 <main+12>:    sub sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000400668 <main+16>:    ldr x0, 0x4006e0 <exit+28>
   0x000000000040066c <main+20>:    mov x1, sp
   0x0000000000400670 <main+24>:    bl  0x4014b0 <__scanf>
   0x0000000000400674 <main+28>:    mov x0, sp
   0x0000000000400678 <main+32>:    bl  0x400680 <revstr>
   0x000000000040067c <main+36>:    add sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000400680 <revstr+0>:   sub sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000400684 <revstr+4>:   str x30, [sp]
   0x0000000000400688 <revstr+8>:   add x9, x19, x0
   0x000000000040068c <revstr+12>:  ldrb    w10, [x9]
   0x0000000000400690 <revstr+16>:  strb    w10, [sp, #8]
   0x0000000000400694 <revstr+20>:  mov w1, w10
   0x0000000000400698 <revstr+24>:  ldr x0, 0x4006e8 <exit+36>
   0x000000000040069c <revstr+28>:  bl  0x401420 <__printf>
   0x00000000004006a0 <revstr+32>:  cbz w10, 0x4006b8 <ret>
   0x00000000004006a4 <revstr+36>:  add x19, x19, #0x1
   0x00000000004006a8 <revstr+40>:  bl  0x400680 <revstr>
   0x00000000004006ac <revstr+44>:  ldr w1, [sp, #8]
   0x00000000004006b0 <revstr+48>:  ldr x0, 0x4006e8 <exit+36>
   0x00000000004006b4 <revstr+52>:  bl  0x401420 <__printf>
   0x00000000004006b8 <ret+0>:      ldr x30, [sp]
   0x00000000004006bc <ret+4>:      add sp, sp, #0x8
   0x00000000004006c0 <ret+8>:      br  x30

frame 0
#0  main () at program.s:11
11                      add x19, xzr, xzr

info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xfffffffff310:
 pc = 0x400658 in main (program.s:11); saved pc = 0x400798
 source language asm.
 Arglist at 0xfffffffff310, args: 
 Locals at 0xfffffffff310, Previous frame's sp is 0xfffffffff310
 

disassemble 0x0000000000400658, 0x00000000004006c0 + 4
Dump of assembler code from 0x400658 to 0x4006c4:
   0x0000000000400658 <main+0>:     add x19, xzr, xzr
   0x000000000040065c <main+4>:     ldr x0, 0x4006d8 <exit+20>
   0x0000000000400660 <main+8>:     bl  0x401420 <__printf>
=> 0x0000000000400664 <main+12>:    sub sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000400668 <main+16>:    ldr x0, 0x4006e0 <exit+28>
   0x000000000040066c <main+20>:    mov x1, sp
   0x0000000000400670 <main+24>:    bl  0x4014b0 <__scanf>
   0x0000000000400674 <main+28>:    mov x0, sp
   0x0000000000400678 <main+32>:    bl  0x400680 <revstr>
   0x000000000040067c <main+36>:    add sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000400680 <revstr+0>:   sub sp, sp, #0x10
   0x0000000000400684 <revstr+4>:   str x30, [sp]
   0x0000000000400688 <revstr+8>:   add x9, x19, x0
   0x000000000040068c <revstr+12>:  ldrb    w10, [x9]
   0x0000000000400690 <revstr+16>:  strb    w10, [sp, #8]
   0x0000000000400694 <revstr+20>:  mov w1, w10
   0x0000000000400698 <revstr+24>:  ldr x0, 0x4006e8 <exit+36>
   0x000000000040069c <revstr+28>:  bl  0x401420 <__printf>
   0x00000000004006a0 <revstr+32>:  cbz w10, 0x4006b8 <ret>
   0x00000000004006a4 <revstr+36>:  add x19, x19, #0x1
   0x00000000004006a8 <revstr+40>:  bl  0x400680 <revstr>
   0x00000000004006ac <revstr+44>:  ldr w1, [sp, #8]
   0x00000000004006b0 <revstr+48>:  ldr x0, 0x4006e8 <exit+36>
   0x00000000004006b4 <revstr+52>:  bl  0x401420 <__printf>
   0x00000000004006b8 <ret+0>:      ldr x30, [sp]
   0x00000000004006bc <ret+4>:      add sp, sp, #0x8
   0x00000000004006c0 <ret+8>:      br  x30
End of assembler dump.
info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0xfffffffff310:
 pc = 0x400664 in main (program.s:16); saved pc = <not saved>
 Outermost frame: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
 source language asm.
 Arglist at 0xfffffffff310, args: 
 Locals at 0xfffffffff310, Previous frame's sp is 0xfffffffff310
```

You are for example not saving `x19`, which is a callee-saved register according to the standard (I suggest reading this IMHO [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078) for a discussion of the semantic for callee-saved.

There seems to be other sections in your program where it is not compliant with the standard, and this is likely causing corruption leading to the segmentation violation fault.

You should therefore make your program compliant, mainly by saving callee-saved registers and adding standard prologues/epilogues to your functions.

I would suggest reading the summarized version of the standard first [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/arm64-windows-abi-conventions?view=msvc-160), as suggested by [Raymond Chen,](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220823-00/?p=107041) , and [this section](https://diveintosystems.org/book/C9-ARM64/functions.html) of the DiveOntoSystem book.

Experimenting with the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) using the -O0 compiler option to inspect code generated for various fucntions by a C compiler for Aarch64 would help as well - see [example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:2),source:%27//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aint+function2(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++char+s%5B31%2B1%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+function1(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++function2(a,b)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm64g1320,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O0%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+ARM64+gcc+13.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Other interesting references can be found at [Codalogic](https://codalogic.com/blog/2022/10/13/Experiments-with-Aarch64-Assembler-Part-4) ,
[Princeton](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr19/cos217/lectures/15_AssemblyFunctions.pdf) and all over the Internet.