# Loop that prints infinite output

Tags: function, assembly, cpu-registers, riscv

Currently using the CREATOR RISC-V simulator: Creator 4.0
RISC-V (RV32IMFD)
didaCtic and geneRic assEmbly progrAmming simulaTOR

I'm trying to do the sin function and I was touching a little bit the float register. I know that, because of convention, I have to use s# and fs# registers.
When executing the code, I get the correct output, but I'm having loops that print to infinite the output. Furthermore, I'm having the error: "Possible failure in the parameter passing convention".

```
.data
pi: .float 3.14159  # Aproximación de pi
valueTest: .float 6.28  # Valor aleatorio para probar [-2pi, 2pi]

.text
main:
    # Llamar a la función sin
    jal ra, sin
    
    # Mover el resultado de la función a un registro adecuado
    # Imprimir el resultado
    li a7, 2  # Código de la llamada al sistema para imprimir una cadena
    ecall

    # Salir del programa
    li a0, 10
    ecall

# Función sin
sin:
    la s0, pi
    flw fs0, 0(s0)  # Cargar el valor de pi (aprox)

    la s1, valueTest
    flw fs1, 0(s1)  # Cargar el valor para probar

    fmul.s fs2, fs0, fs1  # Realizar los cálculos necesarios para la función sin
    fmv.s fa0, fs2
    jr ra  # Retornar al registro de retorno de la función
```

Comment: Please edit your question title, bearing in mind that all-caps is broadly regarded as equivalent to shouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ecall` to terminate the program is incorrectly formed.  Put 10 into `a7` instead of `a0`.

You can observe that the program fails to stop at that point and proceeds on to re-execute the `sin` function even though it wasn't actually called.  Use single step in the debugger.

But because the `ra` register has some arguably legitimate code address value, each time `sin` is *not* invoked, but fallen into, it will return to the last call point where it *was* legitimately called, which is (just after) the `jal sin`.

This results in an infinite loop.

---

You should not use the s# or fs# registers without preserving them.  If you choose to use them, then their original values need to be saved to the stack and restored upon exit.

However, there's no reason to use them in that code — the temporary registers should be used instead, i.e. t# and ft# registers.

We only need saved registers if they can be wiped out by further function calling, and that `sin` does not do any further function calling.

Comment: I thought s# and fs# where used when implementing functions. I know how to do the load by the way. Thanks for the information.

Comment: They are used when implementing *functions that call other functions*, but not for function that don't call anything else.  They are useful in functions that call functions for values that are important enough to merit a register *and are also live across another function call*.  The reason they are useful for that is that every function that uses them also preserves the incoming values in those registers (using the stack to do so).

Comment: @jmartinpizarro: See [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078) for the usual purposes of call-preserved vs. call-clobbered regs.