# Where does stack pointer, %esp, point to after return from function call in assembly?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I have been going through an assembly language tutorial located [here](https://mirrors.sarata.com/non-gnu/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-0-8.pdf) (p.39 if anyone is interested) and am struggling to properly visualize the location of `%esp` upon `ret` from a function. As I understand it, the epilogue to the function:

1. Sets `%esp` to the previously stored value of `%ebp`

> `movl %ebp, %esp`

2. It then pops the original `%ebp` back into `%ebp`, thus increasing the value of `%esp` by 4-bytes.

> `popl %ebp`

3. Upon calling `ret`, the `%eip` value which was pushed onto the stack from the `call` statement, is implicitly popped back into `%eip`, once again increasing `%esp` back to the top value on the stack. This is exactly where it was prior to the function call.

Here is the code in question:

```
 .section .data
 .section .text

 .globl _start
_start:
    pushl $3                
    pushl $2
    call  power
    addl  $8, %esp          #<-- source of my question
    pushl %eax
    pushl $2
    pushl $5
    call  power
    addl  $8, %esp          #<-- source of my question
    popl  %ebx
    addl  %eax, %ebx
    movl  $1, %eax
    int   $0x80

 .type power, @function
power:
    pushl %ebp
    movl  %esp, %ebp
    subl  $4, %esp
    movl  8(%ebp), %ebx     #put first argument in %eax
    movl  12(%ebp), %ecx    #put second argument in %ecx
    movl  %ebx, -4(%ebp)    #store current result

power_loop_start:
    cmpl  $1, %ecx          #if the power is 1, we are done
    je    end_power
    movl  -4(%ebp), %eax    #move the current result into %eax
    imul  %ebx, %eax        #multiply the current result by
                            #the base number
    movl  %eax, -4(%ebp)    #store the current result
    decl  %ecx              #decrease the power
    jmp   power_loop_start  #run for the next power

end_power:
    movl -4(%ebp), %eax     #return value goes in %eax
    movl %ebp, %esp         #restore the stack pointer
    popl %ebp               #restore the base pointer
    ret
```

If it helps, I created an illustration of what *I see* is happening, but I believe I am seeing it wrong. This illustration seeks to capture what is going on until the return of the call to `power`
[image: How I understand what is happening after first call to "power"]

**HERE IS MY QUESTION**

Why does the code, upon returning from `power` point `%esp` backwards 8-bytes? As I see it, and as I hope the picture illustrates my understanding of it, this would place the stack pointer behind the first element on the stack by 4-bytes. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It removes the 2 function arguments again, the ones that got pushed before the call.  That's the cdecl calling convention, there [are others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#pascal) that don't need this

Comment: @HansPassant so, this is essentially programming assembly with a C-framework? Other languages may place arguments on stack in different orders and pop them in different orders, so it's a matter of convention?

Comment: Looks like you copied that code from a chapter titled "Assembly-Language Functions using the C Calling Convention".  So yes, seeing it use the cdecl convention is expected.

Comment: Haha. Didn't realize. I think at this point I'm just trying to get the hang of the very basics. Thanks

Comment: A calling convention can be a thing in a purely asm program.  In that case you *can* use a custom convention for each function and document it with comments, but normally you'd pick one and have most of your functions follow it.  Only some special functions (which are used very often, or are local helpers only used from a couple call sites) would deserve custom calling conventions in most pure-asm projects.  Anything that calls a C library function, or that you want to be callable from C, has to care about C ABIs / calling conventions.

Comment: See [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020) for discussion of what choices can be reasonably justified for custom calling conventions.  My answer points out that it must be possible somehow for the caller to know where the stack pointer is pointing.  cdecl and similar caller-pops conventions return with ESP unmodified from its value before the call, fully [call-preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268586/what-are-callee-and-caller-saved-registers/56178078#56178078).