# CPUs with addressable GPR files, address of register variables, and aliasing between memory and registers

Tags: c, language-lawyer, avr, avr-gcc

### Background

Some CPUs, such as the [Atmel AVR](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf#G1.1180696), have a general purpose register file that is also addressable as part of main memory -- see Figure 7-2 in section 7.4 and the paragraph after the figure.

### What was WG14 thinking?

Given this, why did the C committee choose to make

```
register int ri;
int* pi = &ri;
```

universally ill-formed, as per footnote 101 to [N1124](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) section 6.7.1?  Wouldn't undefined or implementation-defined behavior make more sense, considering that the code above is meaningful on at least one processor, and C bends over backwards to accommodate far stranger (and scarcer!) targets than the AVR?

> 101) The implementation may treat any `register` declaration simply as an `auto` 
>   declaration. However, whether or not addressable storage is actually used, the address 
>   of any part of an object declared with storage-class specifier `register` cannot be 
>   computed, either explicitly (by use of the unary `&` operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) 
>   or implicitly (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in 6.3.2.1). Thus, 
>   the only operator that can be applied to an array declared with storage-class specifier
>   `register` is `sizeof`.

### I just changed a CPU register through a pointer. Wat?!

Furthermore, using the GCC explicit register variables extension, it is possible to direct the compiler to place a variable into a specific register.  In this case, you can get a pointer that aliases with a register variable, as below:

```
register int ri asm("r15") = 0;
int* pi = (int*)0x15;
/* pi now aliases ri */
*pi = 42;
/* ri is 42 now */
assert(ri == 42);
```

How does GCC deal with such a case?  It strikes me as truly bizarre that something like this has not been considered...or has it?

Comment: What would be the use/meaning of your first example snippet (i.e. taking the address of a non-specific register)?

Comment: In the first snippet, `pi` would be set to the memory address of the register -- on the AVR, this is the same as the register number.  As to its uses?  One possibility would be keeping an important variable around for fast access in a complex inner loop, but still allowing subroutines of that inner loop to modify it (as if it had been closed over).

Comment: The question you should be asking is why your GCC doesn't implement this as extension. By default GCC doesn't conform to any standard, so isn't required to treat your first example as an error. (Even in strict compliance most GCC is only required to emit a diagnostic, it could still accept your example with a warning that it's not compliant.)

Comment: @RossRidge: Sounds like I should put a feature request in with the GCC team...would Bugzilla be the correct venue for that?

Comment: Maybe, but you're going to need to make a much better case on why it would be useful. You're going to need to show compelling source code examples that can't be implemented some other way using existing compiler features. A compiler that already implements this would be nice. I'm not sure what the correct place is to make a formal enhancement request is, but discussing it on the GCC mailing list first might be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

C is an abstract language defined without knowledge of the machine that will eventually implement it. The definition of C does not assume that the underlying machine will even *have* registers in the conventional form (or a stack, or contiguous memory, or many other things irrelevant to this question that are present on real machines).

The point being that `register` does *not* mean that the variable should be assigned a machine register. The *meaning of the keyword* is that the variable cannot have its address taken; the compiler is then theoretically able to perform better optimisations on it because it reduces the number of paths through which the variable can potentially be modified. Taking the address of a `register` variable isn't meaningful *in C*, regardless of what processor it runs on, because `register` is [an incredibly badly-named keyword](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/a-common-misconsception-the-register-keyword/) (named for the most obvious optimisation it enables) that *specifically* means the address should not be taken. That is all it means.

An intelligent compiler for the AVR should be able to make that optimisation without needing you to hint at it, anyway (in practice the keyword is useless precisely because any halfdecent compiler can detect when it would be applicable anyway, since there's basically no well-defined way to reference an `auto` object without taking its address explicitly).

Comment: While this is a good explanation of the current *state* of the C standard, it sheds no light as to how WG14 arrived at that definition.

Comment: I don't think that's historically accurate. In older compilers, `register` really did mean "if a register is available, put this variable in it" (on x86 specifically, it tended to do nothing as there were too few registers). Taking the address wasn't possible because on most architectures you can't take addresses of registers. The name was reasonable when that's what it meant.

It's true that since then things have changed, which is why presently `register` as you say simply means it's illegal to take the address, but the name is a hangover from an earlier and simpler time.

Comment: Yeah my comment was wrong. Checking KnR v1 makes it clear that the compiler was originally expected to blindly obey this, in-sequence, and start ignoring it when it ran out of space. Not being able to take the address comes directly from the PDP-11 and is even cited in the book. But later versions of C (post-standardization) do try to be much more abstract about it. It was even voted on for outright removal in C23 (did not pass, it will stay).