# Why are registers needed (why not only use memory)?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

I am just starting to learn Assembly (I have worked with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) before).

I am wondering why do we need to use registers in addition to using memory, why not just use memory?

I guess the most obvious reason is that doing calculations in a register is much faster than doing calculations in memory. But is this the only reason?

Comment: I wasn't totally satisfied with the answers here or on the duplicate I found (especially for this version of the question), so I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360997/assembly-why-are-we-bothering-with-registers/45603798#45603798.  One of the more important differences between registers and memory is that register numbers have to be hard-coded into the machine-code, not indexed, so the CPU always has them right away.  x86 is designed as a register machine, originally for code-density reasons I assume.  That allows high-performance implementations.